# Python Process Pool non-daemonic?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Would it be possible to create a python Pool that is non-daemonic? I want a pool to be able to call a function that has another pool inside.

I want this because deamon processes cannot create process. Specifically, it will cause the error:

```
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

For example, consider the scenario where `function_a` has a pool which runs `function_b` which has a pool which runs `function_c`. This function chain will fail, because `function_b` is being run in a daemon process, and daemon processes cannot create processes.

Comment: AFAIK, no it's not possible all the worker in the pool are daemonized and it's not possible to __inject the dependency__ , BTW i don't understand the second part of your question `I want a pool to be able to call a function that has another pool inside` and how that interfere with the fact that the workers are daemonized.

Comment: Because if function a has a pool which runs function b which has a pool which runs function c, there's a problem in b that it is being run in a daemon process, and daemon processes cannot create processes. `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`

Comment: Instead of importing as `from multiprocessing import Pool`, use `from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class creates the worker processes in its `__init__` method, makes them daemonic and starts them, and it is not possible to re-set their `daemon` attribute to `False` before they are started (and afterwards it's not allowed anymore). But you can create your own sub-class of `multiprocesing.pool.Pool` (`multiprocessing.Pool` is just a wrapper function) and substitute your own `multiprocessing.Process` sub-class, which is always non-daemonic, to be used for the worker processes.

Here's a full example of how to do this. The important parts are the two classes `NoDaemonProcess` and `MyPool` at the top and to call `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` on your `MyPool` instance at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import multiprocessing
# We must import this explicitly, it is not imported by the top-level
# multiprocessing module.
import multiprocessing.pool
import time

from random import randint


class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    # make 'daemon' attribute always return False
    def _get_daemon(self):
        return False
    def _set_daemon(self, value):
        pass
    daemon = property(_get_daemon, _set_daemon)

# We sub-class multiprocessing.pool.Pool instead of multiprocessing.Pool
# because the latter is only a wrapper function, not a proper class.
class MyPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

def sleepawhile(t):
    print("Sleeping %i seconds..." % t)
    time.sleep(t)
    return t

def work(num_procs):
    print("Creating %i (daemon) workers and jobs in child." % num_procs)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_procs)

    result = pool.map(sleepawhile,
        [randint(1, 5) for x in range(num_procs)])

    # The following is not really needed, since the (daemon) workers of the
    # child's pool are killed when the child is terminated, but it's good
    # practice to cleanup after ourselves anyway.
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return result

def test():
    print("Creating 5 (non-daemon) workers and jobs in main process.")
    pool = MyPool(5)

    result = pool.map(work, [randint(1, 5) for x in range(5)])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: The above code seems to be hanging for me. Specifically it appears to hang at pool.close() inside work(). Is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: I just tested my code again with Python 2.7/3.2 (after fixing the "print" lines) on Linux and Python 2.6/2.7/3.2 OS X. Linux and Python 2.7/3.2 on OS X works fine but the code does indeed hang with Python 2.6 on OS X (Lion). This seems to be a bug in the multiprocessing module, which got fixed, but I haven't actually checked the bug tracker.

Comment: This should really be fixed in the multiprocessing module (an option for non-daemonic workers should be available). Does anyone know who maintains it?

Comment: Thanks! On windows you also need to call `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`

Comment: Nice work. If anyone is getting memory leak with this try using "with closing(MyPool(processes=num_cpu)) as pool:" to dispose of the pool properly

Comment: What's the disadvantages of using `MyPool` instead of the default `Pool`? In other words, in exchange for the flexibility of starting child processes, what costs do I pay? (If there were no costs, presumably the standard `Pool` would have used non-daemonic processes).

Comment: @ChrisArndt what would be the license for your code beside the standard CC-CY-SA from SO? MIT?

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: Yes, MIT is fine. Most code I publish, which doesn't have to be GPL, is under MIT license.

Comment: @ChrisArndt Thanks... I am going to put to good use in https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit !

Comment: @machen Yes, unfortunately that's true. In Python 3.6 the `Pool` class has been extensively refactored, so `Process` isn't a simple attribute anymore, but a method, which returns the process instance it gets from a *context*. I tried overwriting this method to return a `NoDaemonPool` instance, but this results in the exception `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children` when the Pool is used.

Comment: Just tested it again with Python 3.7.3, and, to my surprise, this still works. Rather accidentally, though. Overriding `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.Process` circumvents the whole new `context` stuff, and I'm not sure what side-effects this has.

Comment: Confirmed that it works for me in Python 3.6.5 (perhaps the answer was edited to support >=v3.6 after the comment `It doesn't work with python3.6`?

Comment: It doesn't work in Python 3.6.7, most probably due to this commit: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/07b96a95db78eff3557d1bfed1df9ebecc40815b. That commit was reverted already in Python 3.6.8 (https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/10969). So, I guess, it's only in Python 3.6.7 that this solution is not working?

Comment: I just used the answer, but I received this `AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'pool'` error. Why?

Comment: @YanqiHuang Don't forget `import multiprocessing.pool`

Comment: @ChrisArndt I tried `import multiprocessing` and then used `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` as the parent class for the `MyPool` class. Will there be any difference between the two? Thanks

Comment: @YanqiHuang No, that won't work. You need to `import multiprocessing.pool`, exactly as I wrote.

Comment: @ChrisArndt Oh... I see Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ChrisArndt Could you also explain why we need the way as you suggested. Thanks a million. This is just our of my curiosity

Comment: how should this work for celery task? it returns "daemonic processes are not allowed to have children"

Answer (score 58):

I had the necessity to employ a non-daemonic pool in Python 3.7 and ended up adapting the code posted in the accepted answer. Below there's the snippet that creates the non-daemonic pool:

```
import multiprocessing.pool

class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    @property
    def daemon(self):
        return False

    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, value):
        pass


class NoDaemonContext(type(multiprocessing.get_context())):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

# We sub-class multiprocessing.pool.Pool instead of multiprocessing.Pool
# because the latter is only a wrapper function, not a proper class.
class NestablePool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = NoDaemonContext()
        super(NestablePool, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

As the current implementation of `multiprocessing` has been extensively refactored to be based on contexts, we need to provide a `NoDaemonContext` class that has our `NoDaemonProcess` as attribute. `NestablePool` will then use that context instead of the default one.

That said, I should warn that there are at least two caveats to this approach:

1. It still depends on implementation details of the `multiprocessing` package, and could therefore break at any time.
2. There are valid reasons why `multiprocessing` made it so hard to use non-daemonic processes, many of which are explained [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-March/600152.html). The most compelling in my opinion is:

> As for allowing children threads to spawn off children of its own using
> subprocess runs the risk of creating a little army of zombie
> 'grandchildren' if either the parent or child threads terminate before
> the subprocess completes and returns.

Comment: Regarding the caveat: My use case is parallelising tasks, but the grand-children return information to their parents that in turn return information to **their** parents **after** doing some required local processing. Consequently, every level / branch has an explicit wait for all its leafs. Does the caveat still apply if you explicitly have to wait for spawned processes to finish?

Comment: Would you bother adding how to use this instead of multiprocessing.pool?

Comment: "You can now use multiprocessing.Pool and NestablePool interchangeably".

Answer (score 38):

As of Python 3.8, [**`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example) doesn't have this limitation. It can have a nested process pool with no problem at all:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import current_process
import time

def pid():
    return current_process().pid

def _square(i):  # Runs in inner_pool
    square = i ** 2
    time.sleep(i / 10)
    print(f'{pid()=} {i=} {square=}')
    return square

def _sum_squares(i, j):  # Runs in outer_pool
    with Pool(max_workers=2) as inner_pool:
        squares = inner_pool.map(_square, (i, j))
    sum_squares = sum(squares)
    time.sleep(sum_squares ** .5)
    print(f'{pid()=}, {i=}, {j=} {sum_squares=}')
    return sum_squares

def main():
    with Pool(max_workers=3) as outer_pool:
        for sum_squares in outer_pool.map(_sum_squares, range(5), repeat(3)):
            print(f'{pid()=} {sum_squares=}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The above demonstration code was tested with Python 3.8.

A limitation of `ProcessPoolExecutor`, however, is that it doesn't have `maxtasksperchild`. If you need this, consider the [answer by Massimiliano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180921/) instead.

Credit: [answer by jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229030/832230)

Comment: This is now clearly the best solution, as it requires minimal changes.

Comment: works perfectly! ... as a side-note using a child- `multiprocessing.Pool` inside a `ProcessPoolExecutor.Pool` is  also possible!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, still getting `daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`

Comment: @RoyShilkrot Which version of Python are you using exactly?

Comment: python 3.7. The problem was this was run from Celery, and I had to use `import billiard as multiprocessing` and use their `Pool`.

Comment: @RoyShilkrot Noted. The current latest version of Celery claims to support Python 3.8 which is the version of Python that the answer was tested with.

Comment: This won't work if your script is within celery though. Using `celery==4.3.0` and `python==3.7`

Comment: @Acumenus would you mind checking my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305077/how-to-run-a-script-in-parallel-for-different-datasets?noredirect=1#comment120719470_68305077)

Comment: @Opps_0 What's to check. Read the docs of `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, get it to work with something very simple, and then with your actual task.

Answer (score 29):

The [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module has a nice interface to use pools with processes **or** threads. Depending on your current use case, you might consider using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` for your outer Pool, which will result in threads *(that allow to spawn processes from within)* as opposed to processes.

It might be limited by the GIL, but in my particular case *(I tested both)*, the startup time for the processes from the outer `Pool` as created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974695/python-process-pool-non-daemonic/8963618#8963618) far outweighed the solution with `ThreadPool`.

---

It's really easy to swap `Processes` for `Threads`. Read more about how to use a `ThreadPool` solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299004/2889970) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool).

Comment: Thanks - this helped me a lot - great use of threading here (to spawn processes which actually perform well)

Comment: For people looking for a practical solution that probably applies to their situation, this is the one.

Comment: Users choosing a *process* pool are presumably CPU-bound and/or need cancellable tasks, so threads are not an option. This doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

On some Python versions replacing standard Pool to custom can raise error: `AssertionError: group argument must be None for now`.

[Here](https://github.com/nipy/nipype/pull/2754) I found a solution that can help:

```
class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    # make 'daemon' attribute always return False
    @property
    def daemon(self):
        return False

    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, val):
        pass


class NoDaemonProcessPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

    def Process(self, *args, **kwds):
        proc = super(NoDaemonProcessPool, self).Process(*args, **kwds)
        proc.__class__ = NoDaemonProcess

        return proc
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue I encountered was in trying to import globals between modules, causing the ProcessPool() line to get evaluated multiple times.

**globals.py**

```
from processing             import Manager, Lock
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
from pathos.threading       import ThreadPool

class SingletonMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        dict['__deepcopy__'] = dict['__copy__'] = lambda self, *args: self
        return super(SingletonMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(SingletonMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls.instance = None

    def __call__(cls,*args,**kw):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(SingletonMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls.instance

    def __deepcopy__(self, item):
        return item.__class__.instance

class Globals(object):
    __metaclass__ = SingletonMeta
    """     
    This class is a workaround to the bug: AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
     
    The root cause is that importing this file from different modules causes this file to be reevalutated each time, 
    thus ProcessPool() gets reexecuted inside that child thread, thus causing the daemonic processes bug    
    """
    def __init__(self):
        print "%s::__init__()" % (self.__class__.__name__)
        self.shared_manager      = Manager()
        self.shared_process_pool = ProcessPool()
        self.shared_thread_pool  = ThreadPool()
        self.shared_lock         = Lock()        # BUG: Windows: global name 'lock' is not defined | doesn't affect cygwin
```

Then import safely from elsewhere in your code

```
from globals import Globals
Globals().shared_manager      
Globals().shared_process_pool
Globals().shared_thread_pool  
Globals().shared_lock
```

I have written a more expanded wrapper class around `pathos.multiprocessing` here:

- https://github.com/JamesMcGuigan/python2-timeseries-datapipeline/blob/master/src/util/MultiProcessing.py

As a side note, if your usecase just requires async multiprocess map as a performance optimization, then joblib will manage all your process pools behind the scenes and allow this very simple syntax:

```
squares = Parallel(-1)( delayed(lambda num: num**2)(x) for x in range(100) )
```

- https://joblib.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 4):

I have seen people dealing with this issue by using `celery`'s fork of `multiprocessing` called [billiard](https://github.com/celery/billiard) (multiprocessing pool extensions), which allows daemonic processes to spawn children. The walkaround is to simply replace the `multiprocessing` module by:

```
import billiard as multiprocessing
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can start a pool, even if you are in a daemonic process already. This was tested in python 3.8.5

First, define the `Undaemonize` context manager, which temporarily deletes the daemon state of the current process.

```
class Undaemonize(object):
    '''Context Manager to resolve AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
    
    Tested in python 3.8.5'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = multiprocessing.process.current_process()
        if 'daemon' in self.p._config:
            self.daemon_status_set = True
        else:
            self.daemon_status_set = False
        self.daemon_status_value = self.p._config.get('daemon')
    def __enter__(self):
        if self.daemon_status_set:
            del self.p._config['daemon']
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.daemon_status_set:
            self.p._config['daemon'] = self.daemon_status_value
```

Now you can start a pool as follows, even from within a daemon process:

```
with Undaemonize():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
pool.map(... # you can do something with the pool outside of the context manager
```

While the other approaches here aim to create pool that is not daemonic in the first place, this approach allows you to start a pool even if you are in a daemonic process already.

Comment: `current_process()` has been moved to `multiprocessing.current_process()` in the latest python version - tested in Python 3.10.12.

Comment: This is the only solution that works when we are forced to spawn processes, inside of workers spawned using multiprocessing Pool (for eg, in Pytorch dataloader).

Answer (score 1):

This presents a workaround for when the error is seemingly a false-positive. As also [noted by James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479849/), this can happen to an unintentional **import** from a daemonic process.

For example, if you have the following simple code, `WORKER_POOL` can inadvertently be imported from a worker, leading to the error.

```py
import multiprocessing

WORKER_POOL = multiprocessing.Pool()
```

A simple but reliable approach for a workaround is:

```py
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.pool


class MyClass:

    @property
    def worker_pool(self) -> multiprocessing.pool.Pool:
        # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63984747/
        try:
            return self._worker_pool  # type: ignore
        except AttributeError:
            # pylint: disable=protected-access
            self.__class__._worker_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()  # type: ignore
            return self.__class__._worker_pool  # type: ignore
            # pylint: enable=protected-access
```

In the above workaround, `MyClass.worker_pool` can be used without the error. If you think this approach can be improved upon, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python version 3.7 we can create non-daemonic ProcessPoolExecutor

Using `if __name__ == "__main__":` is necessary while using multiprocessing.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool

num_pool = 10
    
def main_pool(num):
    print(num)
    strings_write = (f'{num}-{i}' for i in range(num))
    with Pool(num) as subp:
        subp.map(sub_pool,strings_write)
    return None


def sub_pool(x):
    print(f'{x}')
    return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(num_pool) as p:
        p.map(main_pool,list(range(1,num_pool+1)))
```

Comment: If I change your code and make it return value from both `main_pool` and `sub_pool` then it does not work. `result = p.map(main_pool,list(range(1,num_pool+1)))` instantly returns generator instead of final result