# How to call multiple CPU cores through celery?

Tags: python, celery, python-multiprocessing, celery-task

I'm trying to run a Python script in which it uses multiple CPU cores by "pool.map of multiprocessing". When I run the script through celery it complains that "daemonic processes are not allowed to have children". I use the command below for Celery:

```
sudo celery -A script.celery worker -f LOGFILE -l INFO&
```

I don't know how to make celery call multiple CPU cores for the script.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624290/celery-daemonic-processes-are-not-allowed-to-have-children

Comment: Interestingly when I don't protect the pool.map by "if __name__ == '__main__'", and also when I use --pool=solo for the celery it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple worker

`celery -A project multi start 8 -l INFO -Q:1-2 first_queue, -Q:3-4 second_queue, -Q:5,8 third_queue`

> In this example, 8 workers are assigned; 2 for first_queue, 2 for second_queue and 4 for third_queue.You can assign as many workers as the number of cores and you can change the number of workers you assign depending on the queues.