# How to use all cpus with pathos using nested pools

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

Answering this question about nested pools for multiprocessing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852258/6522112

The code I proposed was not responding the way I wanted. Which is to say if `ThreadingPool(8)` and `ProcessingPool(3)`, I expected the number of processes to be 24 but I only got 3! So I moved on using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963618/6522112 which allows nested process pool by setting the daemon flag to False. This works perfectly but:

1. Was it normal to only get 3 processes instead of 24?
2. Am I doing it correctly with this hack?
3. The final aim would be to do this using several nodes on a cluster. Does this prevent it?
4. I am not sure about the type of `map` to consider but it seems that only the `imap` combination is doing the job. Any insight?

Here is the modified code that uses `pathos` from @MikeMcKerns instead of simple multiprocessing:

```
import pathos
import multiprocess


class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocess.Process):

    """NoDaemonProcess class.

    Inherit from :class:`multiprocessing.Process`.
    ``daemon`` attribute always returns False.

    """

    def _get_daemon(self):
        return False

    def _set_daemon(self, value):
        pass

    daemon = property(_get_daemon, _set_daemon)


class NestedPool(pathos.multiprocessing.Pool):

    """NestedPool class.

    Inherit from :class:`pathos.multiprocessing.Pool`.
    Enable nested process pool.

    """

    Process = NoDaemonProcess
```

Care to be taken if you want to use this, you have to terminate the inner pools otherwise you will end up with zombies:

```
import NestedPool

def triple(x):
    return 3*x

def refork(x):
    pool = NestedPool(3)
    result = pool.imap(triple, range(5))
    result = list(result)
    pool.terminate()
    return result

pool = NestedPool(8)
result = pool.imap(refork, range(3))
```