# Assertion error when inheriting multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I needed a separate process that would open some files on initialization and close them gently at the end. For this, I inherited a class from `Process`. Here is a minimal demo:

```python
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.process import BaseProcess

class Proxy(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy = Proxy()
    proxy.start()
    proxy.join()
```

With this code I get an assertion exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp_proxy.py", line 11, in <module>
    proxy = Proxy()
  File "mp_proxy.py", line 6, in __init__
    super().__init__(self)
  File "/home/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 74, in __init__
    assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
AssertionError: group argument must be None for now
```

The same happens if to replace `Process` with `BaseProcess`. Next I added a debug print into the `process.py`, to the `BaseProcess.__init__` function, just to look at the `group` variable, and then I got something different:

```
multiprocessing.process : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp_proxy.py", line 11, in <module>
    proxy = Proxy()
  File "mp_proxy.py", line 6, in __init__
    super().__init__(self)
  File "/home/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 74, in __init__
    print(__name__, ":", group)
  File "/home/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in __repr__
    elif self._closed:
AttributeError: 'Proxy' object has no attribute '_closed'
```

The question is: How to inherit Process in a proper way? Maybe the concept I took is wrong?

Earlier, in another post '[Error group argument must be None for now in multiprocessing.pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948447/error-group-argument-must-be-none-for-now-in-multiprocessing-pool)' a similar error was described, however I did not see a solution to the problem. As far as I understood, the behavior is highly dependent on the Python sub-version. It's not cool at all.

P.S.: Ubuntu 20.04, Anaconda 3 with Python 3.7.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `super().__init__()` instead of `super().__init__(self)`.

[`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) in this case translates to `super(Proxy, self)`, already binding the super-object to your `Proxy`-instance. You *call* methods on the super-object like you always do with methods, *without* explicitly passing `self`.

`group` is the second parameter in `BaseProcess.__init__(self, group=None, target=None...)` and with calling `super().__init__(self)` in your code, you're setting it to `self`, hence the `AssertionError`.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake. Thank you! However, I can't interpret the second error, when I tried the debug output: `AttributeError: 'Proxy' object has no attribute '_closed'`

Comment: @EvgenyP.Kurbatov I didn't manage to replicate this particular error, but anyway, `multiprocessing.process.BaseProcess` isn't complete and ready to be subclassed by users. Use `multiprocessing.Process` (`multiprocessing.context.Process`) instead.