# how to fan out multiple processes from multiple processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a task which needs to run a number of subtasks, each on their own vm, and then when all subtasks are complete, merge the results and present them back to the caller.

I have implemented this using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, and it's working great.

I now want to scale up, running multiple of these tasks in parallel.

My initial design was to wrap my task running in another `multiprocessing.Pool`, where each task runs in its process, effectively fanning out as follows:

```
job
+----- task_a
|      +------ subtask_a1
|      +------ subtask_a2
|      +------ subtask_a3
+----- task_b
       +------ subtask_b1
       +------ subtask_b2
       +------ subtask_b3
```

- `job` starts a `multiprocessing.Pool` with 2 processes, one for `task_a` and one for `task_b`.
- in turn, `task_a` and `task_b` each start a `multiprocessing.Pool` with 3 processes, one for each of their subtasks.

When I tried to run my code, I hit an assertion error:

```
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

Searching online for details, I found the [following thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-March/600152.html), an excerpt of which reads:

> As for allowing children threads to spawn off children of its own using 
>   subprocess runs the risk of creating a little army of zombie 
>   'grandchildren' if either the parent or child threads terminate before 
>   the subprocess completes and returns

I have also found [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963618/955273) which allow this kind of "pool within a pool" use:

```
class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    @property
    def daemon(self):
        return False

    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, value):
        pass

class NoDaemonContext(type(multiprocessing.get_context())):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

class MyPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = NoDaemonContext()
        super(MyPool, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, given the above quote about "zombie grandchildren", it seems perhaps this is not a good design.

So I guess my question is:

- What is the pythonic way to "fan out" multiple processes within multiple processes"?