# How to create a pool inside another pool without daemonic error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to create a `pool` inside a `pool` and I seem to get an error I cannot correct, even by searching the error. **Here is the code**:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
cpus = mp.cpu_count() - 1
def f(x):
    pool1 = mp.Pool(cpus)
    lista = list(pool1.map(sleep, [60] * 1000))
    pool1.close()
    pool1.join()
    return lista

pool2 = mp.Pool(cpus)
lista2 = pool2.map(f, range(1000))
pool2.close()
pool2.join()
```

**Here is the error**: `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`
I don't know why I am getting this error since I properly `close` and `join` every `pool`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Process Pool non-daemonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974695/python-process-pool-non-daemonic)

Comment: Yes and no. It seems to be able to create a pool inside a pool but I don't really understand how it is done