# Pool issue when called from parent pool Python

Tags: python-3.x, nested, multiprocessing

test1.py/myfunc1() does some work in parallel.

If I call myfunc1() from test2.py - it works fine (currently commented out).

If I create another pool in test2.py and call myfunc1() from those I get an unreported error in test1.py on the "pool = mp.Pool(5)" line .

> result = {type} <class 'AssertionError'>  args = {getset_descriptor}
> <attribute 'args' of 'BaseException' objects>

How do I fix this issue?

```
test1.py

import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(a):
    print("Worker: "+str(a))
    time.sleep(5)
    return a

def mycallback(val ):
    print("Callback: "+str(val))


def myfunc1(n=3):
    print("start myfunc1")
    slist = range(n)
    pool = mp.Pool(5)
    [pool.apply_async(worker,args=(s,), callback=mycallback) for s in slist]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunc1()



test2.py

from pythonProjectTEST.test1 import myfunc1
import multiprocessing as mp

def mycallback(val ):
    print("CallbackMaster: "+str(val))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This works
    #myfunc1(5)

    # This does not
    slist = range(6)
    pool = mp.Pool(3)
    [pool.apply_async(myfunc1,args=(s,), callback=mycallback) for s in slist]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Please include the error details.

Comment: OK, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to spawn a daemon process from another daemon process.  Note how the main of `test2` spawns processes to call `myfunc1` and then `myfunc1` spawns processes to call `worker`. I suspect this restriction is to reduce the chances of fork bombs or deadlocks.  If you really want to do this, there are workarounds: [Python Process Pool non-daemonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974695/python-process-pool-non-daemonic). However, I would avoid it if possible.

To debug an issue like this, it is often convenient to add an error callback.  For example, the following code gives you a helpful error message "Error: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children":

```
def errorcallback(val):
    print("Error: %s" % str(val))
 ...
[pool.apply_async(myfunc1,args=(s,), callback=mycallback, error_callback=errorcallback ) for s in slist]
```

The method `apply_async` will normally eat errors unless you specify an error_calblack (see [the documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)).  The arguments in square brackets are optional, but you can add them one by one with the specified names.

```
apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback[, error_callback]]]])
```

"If error_callback is specified then it should be a callable which accepts a single argument. If the target function fails, then the error_callback is called with the exception instance."