# python, how to incrementally create Threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a list of items aprox 60,000 items - i would like to send queries to the database to check if they exist and if they do return some computed results. I run an ordinary query, while iterating through the list one-by-one, the query has been running for the last 4 days. I thought i  could use the threading module to improve on this. I did something like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  for ra, dec in candidates:
    t = threading.Thread(target=search_sl, args=(ra,dec, q))
    t.start()
  t.join()
```

I tested with only 10 items and it worked fine - when i submitted the whole list of 60k items, i run into errors i.e, "maximum number of sessions exceeded". What I want to do is to create maybe 10 thread at a time. When the 1st bunch of thread have finished excuting, i send another request and so on.

Comment: I don't think threads are the solution to your problem.  You should probably rather reduce the number of database queries.  Could you post details on the individual queries that you currently perform?

Comment: @SvenMarnach,i run the query thru python, another class translates the queries to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you join only the last thread. There is no guarantee that it will be finished the last. You should use like that:

```
from time import sleep
delay = 0.5
tlist = [threading.Thread(target=search_sl, args=(ra,dec, q)) for ra, dec in candidates ]
map(lambda t:t.start(), tlist)
while(any(map(lambda t:t.isAlive()))): sleep(delay)
```

The second issue is the running 60K threads at the moment requires really huge hardware resource :-) It's better to queue your tasks and then process by workers. The number of worker threads must be limited. Like that (haven't tested the code, but the idea is clear I hope):

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
tasks = Queue()
map(tasks.put, candidates)
maxthreads = 50
delay = 0.1
try:
    threads = [Thread(target=search_sl, args=tasks.get()) \
               for i in xrange(0,maxthreads) ]
except Queue.Empty:
    pass
map(lambda t:t.start(), threads)

while not tasks.empty():
    threads = filter(lambda t:t.isAlive(), threads)
    while len(threads) < maxthreads:
        try:
            t = Thread(target=search_sl, args=tasks.get())
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
        except Queue.Empty:
            break
    sleep(delay)

while(any(map(lambda t:t.isAlive(), threads))): sleep(delay)
```

Comment: been trying to follow your example. unfortunately, its my 1st time to work with threads, 'tlist' is not defined. is it supposed to be tasks/threads? tried both, still get errors with iterables

Comment: @user739807 I've just fixed some errors. I have no chance to run the code and test it now.

Comment: @user739807 I didn't take into account 'q' parameter --- deal with this by yourself.

Answer (score 7):

You could try using a process pool, which is available in the multiprocessing module.  Here is the example from the python docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Try increasing the number of processes until you reach the maximum your system can support.

Comment: That's not a thread pool, but rather a process pool -- which of course does not make too much of a difference here.

Comment: You can of course do the same thing with threads as Mikey explained with multiprocessing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool

Answer (score 4):

#### Improve your queries before threading (premature optimization is the root of all evil!)

Your problem is having 60,000 different queries on a single database. Having a single query for each item means a lot of overhead for opening the connection and invoking a DB cursor session.

Threading those queries can speed up your process, but yields another set of problems like DB overload and max sessions allowed.

#### First approach: Load many item IDs into every query

Instead, try to improve your queries. Can your write a query that sends a long list of products and returns the matches? Perhaps something like:

```
SELECT item_id, * 
FROM   items
WHERE  item_id IN (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, ....)
```

Python gives you convenient interfaces for this kind if queries, so that the `IN` clause can use a pythonic list. This way you can break your long list of items to, say, 60 queries with 1,000 ids each.

#### Second approach: Use a temporary table

Another interesting approach is creating a temporary table on the database with your item ids. Temporary tables lasts as long as the connection lives, so you won't have to worry about cleanups. Perhaps something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
           item_ids_list (id INT PRIMARY KEY); # Remember indexing!
```

Insert the ids using an appropriate Python library:

```
INSERT INTO item_ids_list   ...                # Insert your 60,000 items here
```

Get your results:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.id IN (SELECT * FROM items_ids_list);
```

Comment: will take to the database admin, about this! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an IO task, neither of thread or process is good for it. You use those if you need to parallelize computational tasks. So, be modern please ™, use something like `gevent` for parallel IO intensive tasks.

http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example