# Why does the instance need to be recreated when restarting a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

Imagine the following classes:

```
Class Object(threading.Thread):
    # some initialisation blabla
    def run(self):
        while True:
            # do something
            sleep(1)

class Checker():
    def check_if_thread_is_alive(self):
        o = Object()
        o.start()

        while True:
            if not o.is_alive():
                o.start()
```

I want to restart the thread in case it is dead. This doens't work. Because the threads can only be started once. First question. Why is this?

For as far as I know I have to recreate each instance of `Object` and call `start()` to start the thread again. In case of complex `Object`s this is not very practical. I've to read the current values of the old `Object`, create a new one and set the parameters in the new object with the old values. Second question: Can this be done in a smarter, easier way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason why threading.Thread is implemented that way is to keep correspondence between a thread object and operating system's thread. In major OSs threads can not be restarted, but you may create another thread **with another thread id**.

If recreation is a problem, there is no need to inherit your class from threading.Thread, just pass a target parameter to Thread's constructor like this:

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
    def run(self):
        ...
```

Then you may access thread member to control your thread execution, and recreate it as needed. No MyObj recreation is required.

Answer (score 1):

See here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start

> It must be called at most once per thread object. It arranges for the
>   object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.
>
> This method will raise a RuntimeError if called more than once on the
>   same thread object.

A thread isn't intended to run more than once. You might want to use a [Thread Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that has to do with how `Thread` class is implemented. It wraps a real OS thread, so that restarting the thread would actually change its identity, which might be confusing.

A better way to deal with threads is actually through target functions/callables:

```
class Worker(object):
    """ Implements the logic to be run in separate threads """
    def __call__(self):
        #  do useful stuff and change the state

class Supervisor():
    def run(self, worker):
        thr = None
        while True:
            if not thr or not thr.is_alive():
                thr = Thread(target=worker)
                thr.daemon = True
                thr.start()
            thr.join(1)  # give it some time
```