# Execute Thread 5 by 5

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a huge list of information and my program should analyze each one of them. To speed up I want to use threads, but I want to limit them by 5. So I need to make a loop with 5 threads and when one finish their job grab a new one till the end of the list.
But I don't have a clue how to do that. Should I use queue? For now I just running 5 threads in the most simple way:
Thank you!

```
for thread_number in range (5):
    thread = Th(thread_number)
    thread.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the idea of worker thread and task -- do not have one worker work on one task, then terminate the thread. Instead, spawn 5 threads, and let them all get tasks from a common queue. Let them each iterate until they receive a sentinel from the queue which tells them to quit.

This is more efficient than continually spawning and terminating threads after they complete just one task.

```
import logging
import Queue
import threading
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
N = 100
sentinel = object()

def worker(jobs):
    name = threading.current_thread().name
    for task in iter(jobs.get, sentinel):
        logger.info(task)
    logger.info('Done')


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format='[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%H:%M:%S')

    jobs = Queue.Queue()
    # put tasks in the jobs Queue
    for task in range(N):
        jobs.put(task)

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(jobs,))
               for thread_number in range (5)]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
        jobs.put(sentinel)     # Send a sentinel to terminate worker
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm trying to use this in my case. Will improve a lot the job.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want a thread pool. If you're using python 3, you're lucky : there is a [ThreadPoolExecutor class](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor)

Else, from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool), you can find various solutions, either handcrafted or using hidden modules from the python library.

Comment: Thank you! This question have a lot of useful answers!