# Execute multiple threads concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading

Current code is:

```
def export_data(file):
    <runs the db2 database command to export tables to file>

def export_to_files(yaml):
    logger = logging.getLogger("export_to_files")
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=export_data, args=[out_file1])
    thread1.start()
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=export_data, args=[out_file2])
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

def main():
    export_to_files()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My understanding was that `join()` only blocks the calling thread. However, I did not realize that `thread1.join()` would even block `thread2` from executing, essentially making the code to only run 1 thread i.e. `thread1`.

How can I execute both the threads concurrently, while have the main thread wait for both to complete?

EDIT: I stand corrected, the 2 threads do run, but it seems like only 1 thread is actually "doing" things at a point in time.

To elaborate further, the `callable_method` is reading data from the database and writing to a file. While I can now see 2 files being updated(each thread writes to a separate file), one of the files is not updated for quite some time now, while the other file is up-to-date as to current time.

There is **no** connection object being used. The queries are run from the db2 command line interface.

Comment: `thread1.join()` should not be preventing `thread2` from executing.

Comment: The threads start running when you call their `.start()` method. `.join()` blocks until a thread _stops_.

Comment: Have you tried removing the join() calls? It should execute as expected if you do that.

Comment: @Surveon If OP does that, the program will immediately exit (assuming the code he posted is the complete program).

Comment: I have updated to my post to reflect my scenario

Comment: @articSnail Regarding your update, do you have another question? Since we can't see your threads' code, there's not much we can do as far as telling you why one of the files is not being updated often.

Comment: Do you use the same *connection* to your DB in both of your threads?

Comment: @JosephDunn: I have updated the code, though it is pretty much the same as the original pseudo code. I am not sure if adding the actual db2 command would help. Please let me know

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: No, I am using the DB2 command line interface to run the queries and output to a file

Comment: @articSnail Well, one thing you could do is temporarily replace your threads' code with a loop that prints something uniquely identifying that thread, and sleeps for a second. This would clear up any doubts about the problem being in the code you've posted.

Comment: @articSnail I have added an example of what I'm referring to as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the largely undocumented [`ThreadPool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3386632/355230) class in `multiprocessing.pool` to do something along these lines:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import random
import threading
import time

MAX_THREADS = 2
print_lock = threading.Lock()

def export_data(fileName):
    # simulate writing to file
    runtime = random.randint(1, 10)
    while runtime:
        with print_lock: # prevent overlapped printing
            print('[{:2d}] Writing to {}...'.format(runtime, fileName))
        time.sleep(1)
        runtime -= 1

def export_to_files(filenames):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=MAX_THREADS)
    pool.map_async(export_data, filenames)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()  # block until all threads exit

def main():
    export_to_files(['out_file1', 'out_file2', 'out_file3'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example output:

```
[ 9] Writing to out_file1...
[ 6] Writing to out_file2...
[ 5] Writing to out_file2...
[ 8] Writing to out_file1...
[ 4] Writing to out_file2...
[ 7] Writing to out_file1...
[ 3] Writing to out_file2...
[ 6] Writing to out_file1...
[ 2] Writing to out_file2...
[ 5] Writing to out_file1...
[ 1] Writing to out_file2...
[ 4] Writing to out_file1...
[ 8] Writing to out_file3...
[ 3] Writing to out_file1...
[ 7] Writing to out_file3...
[ 2] Writing to out_file1...
[ 6] Writing to out_file3...
[ 1] Writing to out_file1...
[ 5] Writing to out_file3...
[ 4] Writing to out_file3...
[ 3] Writing to out_file3...
[ 2] Writing to out_file3...
[ 1] Writing to out_file3...
```

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates a runnable version of your example code:

```
import time
import threading

def export_data(fileName):
    # runs the db2 database command to export tables to file
    while True:
        print 'If I were the real function, I would be writing to ' + fileName
        time.sleep(1)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=export_data, args=[ 'out_file1' ])
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=export_data, args=[ 'out_file2' ])

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your visible code is fine, however some code invisible to us does use locking, the locking can happen even in the database itself.