# How to limit number of concurrent threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

How can I limit the number of concurrent threads in Python?

For example, I have a directory with many files, and I want to process all of them, but only 4 at a time in parallel.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def process_file(fname):
        # open file and do something                                                                                            

def process_file_thread(queue, fname):
    queue.put(process_file(fname))

def process_all_files(d):
    files=glob.glob(d + '/*')
    q=Queue.Queue()
    for fname in files:
        t=threading.Thread(target=process_file_thread, args=(q, fname))
        t.start()
    q.join()

def main():
    process_all_files('.')
    # Do something after all files have been processed
```

How can I modify the code so that only 4 threads are run at a time?

Note that I want to wait for all files to be processed and then continue and work on the processed files.

Comment: Have you tried [multiprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) Pools? On Python 3 you can also use [futures](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html).

Comment: You can use [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) in Python 2 also, you just need to install the backport.

Comment: concurrent.futures is indeed the best way to do it

Comment: You could use a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to easily limit the number of threads, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18283388/355230) to another question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> For example, I have a directory with many files, and I want to process all of them, but only 4 at a time in parallel.

That's exactly what a thread pool does: You create jobs, and the pool runs 4 at a time in parallel. You can make things even simpler by using an executor, where you just hand it functions (or other callables) and it hands you back futures for the results. You can build all of this yourself, but you don't have to.*

The stdlib's [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module is the easiest way to do this. (For Python 3.1 and earlier, see the [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures).) In fact, [one of the main examples](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/concurrent.futures.html) is very close to what you want to do. But let's adapt it to your exact use case:

```
def process_all_files(d):
    files = glob.glob(d + '/*')
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        fs = [executor.submit(process_file, file) for file in files]
        concurrent.futures.wait(fs)
```

If you wanted `process_file` to return something, that's almost as easy:

```
def process_all_files(d):
    files = glob.glob(d + '/*')
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        fs = [executor.submit(process_file, file) for file in files]
        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(fs):
            do_something(f.result())
```

And if you want to handle exceptions too… well, just look at the example; it's just a `try`/`except` around the call to `result()`.

---

* If you want to build them yourself, it's not that hard. The source to [`multiprocessing.pool`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py) is well written and commented, and not that complicated, and most of the hard stuff isn't relevant to threading; the source to [`concurrent.futures`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/concurrent/futures) is even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I used this technique a few times, I think it's a bit ugly thought:

```
import threading

def process_something():
    something = list(get_something)

    def worker():
        while something:
            obj = something.pop()
            # do something with obj

   threads = [Thread(target=worker) for i in range(4)]
   [t.start() for t in threads]
   [t.join() for t in threads]
```