# Python Semaphore does not seem to work in Google Colab

Tags: python, multithreading, google-colaboratory

I am trying to follow this example

[limit number of threads working in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173808/limit-number-of-threads-working-in-parallel)

To limit the number of threads I am working with.

When I try this code

```
import threading
import time

maxthreads = 5
sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
threads = list()

def task(i):
    sema.acquire()
    print( "start %s" % (i,))
    time.sleep(2)
    sema.release()

for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(str(i)))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

This is the output

```
start 0start 1
start 3start 2


start 4
```

the 2nd half of the output does not come. Perhaps this is something to do with colab?

If so, is there a recommended way to limit the number of threads in colab multithreading?

I also tried boundedsemaphore, same result

```
import threading
import time

maxthreads = 5
sema = threading.BoundedSemaphore(maxthreads)
threads = list()

def task(i):
    sema.acquire()
    print( "start %s" % (i,))
    time.sleep(2)
    sema.release()

for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(str(i)))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: I've now come back to this answer after some time to provide some more insight, having realized that my original answer was probably wrong. I've included a description of the problem which I think is interesting by itself, but you can skip it and go straight to a possible solution.

### The problem

I originally thought that the issue was that Google Colab was prematurely stopping the process/threads when they were inactive. While that seemed reasonable at the time, I've realized that the answer is much simpler.

The issue here is that the main thread is not waiting for the created threads to end. After the main thread is done, Google Colab does not seem to wait for the other threads to end, and so the output they produce never reaches the main console. The following code runs as expected locally:

```
import threading
import time

maxthreads = 2
sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
threads = list()

def task(i):
    sema.acquire()
    print( "start %s" % (i,))
    time.sleep(2)
    sema.release()

for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

Saving it locally to a file and running it yields:

```
start 0
start 1
start 2
start 3
start 4
start 5
start 6
start 7
start 8
start 9
```

However when running it in Google Colab (you can [try it here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZtX8XZgKSzfBeJNA3OUVNc8WCzNbIDDB)) we get:

```
start 0
start 1
```

What's going on internally (I assume) is that the main thread is done, and then Google Colab doesn't wait for all the other threads to end. We only see the first to threads' output because those run fast enough that they are done before the main thread ends. An interesting experiment is to print something when the main thread is done:

```
import threading
import time

maxthreads = 2
sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
threads = list()

def task(i):
    sema.acquire()
    print( "start %s" % (i,))
    time.sleep(2)
    sema.release()

for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

print('Main thread done')
```

We get the following output (output from running locally on the left, output from running on Google Colab on the right):

```
Locally:                      Google colab:
---------------------------------------
start 0              |        start 0
start 1              |        start 1
Main thread done     |        Main thread done
start 2              |
start 3              |
start 4              |
start 5              |
start 6              |
start 7              |
start 8              |
start 9              |
```

Indeed we see that once the main thread is done, the rest of the output is lost on Google Colab.

### A solution

We can make use of `Thread.join()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)) to wait until a thread is done. That way, we can make the main process wait for all the additional threads before finishing (you can try it in Google Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RMnzhhkyPxY7-OOHvcWkpArwzMtmyg9z)):

```
import threading
import time

maxthreads = 2
sema = threading.Semaphore(value=maxthreads)
threads = list()

def task(i):
    sema.acquire()
    print( "start %s" % (i,))
    time.sleep(2)
    sema.release()

for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

And the output is the same, both locally and in Google Colab:

```
start 0
start 1
start 2
start 3
start 4
start 5
start 6
start 7
start 8
start 9
```

You can also try adding `print('Main thread done')` at the end, and you'll see that it will be printed only when all the additional threads are done.

---

On an unrelated note, you should probably change

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(str(i)))
```

To

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=task,args=(i,))
```

Or you might get problems when `i` is a two-digit number. Note that `(i,)` is a tuple with `i` as its single element.

Comment: Thanks. One quick question, do you know the point of `threads = list()` and `threads.append(thread)` in the given example?

Comment: In some cases it might be useful to have a list of your threads so you can refer to them later. This is especially useful when debugging or when you're first learning how to multithread, you can inspect your thread objects at different points in time to see their status to check if they started running or they are already stopped, etc. In this particular example the threads list isn't really used so you could just remove those two lines.

Comment: What should be done if lets say, I need to run two infinite loops in parallel using two Processes/threads? I can't use join here because I want both of these infinite loops running parallelly for a long period of time.