# How to continuously updating the display in two different place in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I know how to print one line in same plase but I want to print same place from thread only.

Now I'm getting:

> ```
> OK 97035
> ```

I want to get:

> ```
> OK 97035 
> OK 92035
> ```

First line is from t1 thread, second from t2 thread. Anyone know how to do it ?

This is sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import string, threading

def test():
    for i in range(0, 100000):
        print "\rOK "+str(i),

jczyd= ['1', '2']


while True:
        for i in jczyd:
                if i == '1':
                        #print i
                        t1 = threading.Thread(target=test, args = ())
                        t1.daemon = True
                        t1.start()
                elif i == '2':
                        #print i
                        t2 = threading.Thread(target=test, args = ())
                        t2.daemon = True
                        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python print end=' '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end)

Comment: I saw this, but there are only print on same line but how to print in other lines text from other thread.

Comment: The problem is the display is global resource, so you need a `lock` to control access to it. See the `print_lock` variable in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18283388/355230) of mine for example.

Comment: This has nothing to do with display locking, `print(end=' ')`, or anything like that. This is a problem of continuously updating the display in two different places.

Comment: @nneonneo: Updating the display in two different places (threads) is exactly what adding a `lock` to the display would prevent.

Comment: @nneonneo: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is trickier than you might think.

The problem is that there's no character in plain ASCII that you can use to update two separate lines of text simultaneously. `\r` only lets you erase one line.

If you want to update two lines you will have to use a platform-specific method, like ANSI escape codes, or use `curses` to control the terminal in a more general way.

On most UNIX systems, you can do this with code like this:

```
print '\x1b[%dH%s\x1b[K' % (thread_id, i)
```

which sets the cursor to the `thread_id`th line, prints `i`, then erases the rest of the line.

Comment: Or you could try to print both in one line and polling for the variables from the main thread.

Comment: What I should put into `thread_id` ? I put `1` and have this error
`TypeError: test() argument after * must be a sequence, not int`

Comment: There's no `*` anywhere in my code: this is something else.