# Multiple threads in while loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a simple problem / question about the below code.

```
ip = '192.168.0.'
count = 0
while count <= 255:
    print(count)
    count += 1
    for i in range(10):
        ipg=ip+str(count)
        t = Thread(target=conn, args=(ipg,80))
        t.start()
```

I want to execute 10 threads each time and wait for it to finish and then continue with the next 10 threads until count <= 255

I understand my problem and why it does execute 10 threads for every count increase, but not how to solve it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess I should add a Queue

Comment: Consider using the largely undocumented [`ThreadPool`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3386632/355230) class in `multiprocessing.pool` with `ThreadPool(processes=10)`. You could use `while not(all(a_thread.ready() for a_thread in results)): pass` to wait for all 10 threads to be idle each iteration. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18283388/355230) to another question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at the moment I'm working with a queue list but i guess the advantage with a pool is that after one process of the 10 is done it starts an other instead of waiting before all 10 have finsihed. Right ?

Comment: True, but if you feed it 10 things at a time and then wait for them all to finish before feeding any more into it, you'll be able to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can easily achieved using [concurrents.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library

here's the example code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 

ip = '192.168.0.'
count = 0

THREAD_COUNT = 10

def work_done(future):
    result = future.result()
    # work with your result here


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_COUNT) as executor:
        while count <= 255:
            count += 1
            ipg=ip+str(count)
            executor.submit(conn, ipg, 80).add_done_callback(work_done)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here executor returns future for every task it submits.
keep in mind that if you use `add_done_callback()` finished task from thread returns to the **main thread** (which would block your main thread) if you really want true parallelism then you should wait for future objects separately. here's the code snippet for that.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures._base import wait

futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_COUNT) as executor:
    while count <= 255:
        count += 1
        ipg=ip+str(count)
        futures.append(executor.submit(conn, ipg, 80))
wait(futures)

for succeded, failed in futures:
    # work with your result here
```

hope this helps!

Comment: In prefer this answer because ThreadPoolExecutor seems the best way to follow. Other answers where also correct. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

There are two viable options: [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html#module-queue) with `ThreadPool` as @martineau suggested and using [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html#module-queue). Here's an example with `queue` that executes requests concurrently in 10 different threads. Note that it doesn't do any kind of batching, as soon as a thread completes it picks up next task without caring the status of other workers:

```
import queue
import threading

def conn():
    try:
        while True:
            ip, port = que.get_nowait()
            print('Connecting to {}:{}'.format(ip, port))
            que.task_done()
    except queue.Empty:
        pass

que = queue.Queue()
for i in range(256):
    que.put(('192.168.0.' + str(i), 80))

# Start workers
threads = [threading.Thread(target=conn) for _ in range(10)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

# Wait que to empty
que.join()

# Wait workers to die
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Output:

```
Connecting to 192.168.0.0:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.1:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.2:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.3:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.4:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.5:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.6:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.7:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.8:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.9:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.10:80
Connecting to 192.168.0.11:80
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so that it has correct **logic** to do what you want. Please note that I don't run it but hope you'll get the general idea:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

ip = '192.168.0.'
count = 0
while count <= 255:
    print(count)
    # a list to keep your threads while they're running
    alist = []
    for i in range(10):
        # count must be increased here to count threads to 255
        count += 1
        ipg=ip+str(count)
        t = Thread(target=conn, args=(ipg,80))
        t.start()
        alist.append(t)

    # check if threads are still running
    while len(alist) > 0:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        for t in alist:
            if not t.isAlive():
                # remove completed threads
                alist.remove(t)
```