# Pythonic way for managing thread pool

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a couple of python scripts that are responsible for managing some live feed processing.  Its structured like so:

**Script 1:** manages an "aggregate" list of live events that provides some very thin data about all events.

**Script 2:** manages a list of threads that process detailed feeds for each live event.

Script 1 is responsible for defining which events are active and (for now) writes all the unique identifiers for the active events to a flat file (not liking that at all).  Script 2 reads those unique identifiers, checks to see if it already has a thread with that ID and if not, it starts that thread which then processes the detailed data for that event.  Script 2 does NOT define when that thread should be marked as inactive or remove it from the quasi-queue file.  The threads know when they should terminate themselves and script 1 monitors a feed that is the master list which defines what events are active.  This works but fairly well but it feels clunky and poor to me.

I've looked at this [Threading pool similar to the multiprocessing Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool) and Queue approaches like this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/ but they don't seem to apply well because the live event threads don't have a specified lifespan...they are spawned and live until their event is over (in the order of hours).

I'm still new to python and this feels a bit over my head.  Any kind of sanity/stupidity check you could offer in terms of implementation approaches would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm not in a position to use an external module because of sys admin limitations :(

Comment: You can always put a copy of a third-party module into your project.  I assume you're allowed to install *your* project on the target system. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use something like [`celery`.](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: I'm not in a position to use an external module because of sys admin limitations :(

Comment: @Brad That's completely untrue unless you cannot write any files and cannot access the shell.