# Execute multi threaded program in Python to run as single thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, single-threaded

I've been using threading class alot in my Python codes and have successfully make a couple routine to run as multi-threaded. The problem is when something fails, it becomes a pain when it comes to debugging. This is what my code block would look like:

```
threads = []
for argument in get_file_method():
    thread = threading.Thread(self._routine, argument)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    filename = thread.join()
```

The question is, How can I force the program to run as single threaded in order to ease debug.

Comment: that doesn't make sense.  when would the routines run and in what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`dummy_threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dummy_threading.html) module in standard library that you can use instead of `threading`. It offers the same inteface but runs code sequentially (`start` returns when the thread has finished). Of course, your threads must  not rely on each other to work in parallel.

```
import dummy_threading as threading
```

Comment: Thanks Janne Karila, this helps. But, is there a method i can explicitly specify how many threads the program is allowed to spawn?

Comment: @superface I would say that your program should control how many threads it spawns. Maybe this is useful to you: [Python thread pool similar to the multiprocessing Pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3033952/222914)

Comment: The `dummy_threading` module was removed in Python 3.9.  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dummy_threading'`