# Is there any mechanism in Python to control the maximum of multi thread?

Tags: java, python, multithreading

I'd like to have something like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)` which is in Java.

That is to say, I want my python program **to fork at most 3 multi thread at a time**, if the number of multi thread is 3 for now, wait until the number is less than 3.

Is there anything like that in python? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Something like [this](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)?

Comment: If I didn't get that wrong, it's for multiprocessing? What I want is for multithreading. Anyway, thanks for a silver lining :) @RedBaron

Comment: Yes it is. You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool) for threads. Aside, IMO GIL really inhibits threading in Python and if possible you should consider multiprocessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the what you need is a [semaphore object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects):

```
threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(maximumNumberOfThreads)

class YourThread(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        threadLimiter.acquire()
        try:
            <your code here>
        finally:
            threadLimiter.release()
```

When you start threads more than maximum number of threads, the exceeding threads will wait in `threadLimiter.acquire()` till the end of some threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running python 3.2+, you have access to `concurrent.futures`, a high-level threading module which conveniently refers to its interface as `Executor`.  It comes in both `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor` flavors.

```
#adapted example from docs
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    future_results = [executor.submit(my_func, *args) for _ in range(100000)]
    for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_results):
        #do something with each result
```

More fleshed-out example of retrieving the results of many `urllib.request` calls can be [found in the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).  It should be noted that that is what you should be using many threads for - tasks that are I/O bound.  Tasks that are processor-bound will not benefit from multithreading due to the GIL - for that, use `ProcessPoolExecutor` (which leverages `multiprocessing`).

Comment: @Judking bummer.  I'll leave the answer up in case it helps someone else.  Good luck working with those `threading` primitives :)