# Distinguishing the return values from threads when a queue is used

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

This is my code :

```
  queue=Queue.Queue()
    isbn=str(9789382711056)
    thread1= Thread(target = amazon, args=[isbn,queue])
    thread2= Thread(target = bookadda, args=[isbn,queue])
    thread3= Thread(target = infibeam, args=[isbn,queue])
    def jo():
        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()
        thread3.join()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()

   jo()
```

And each of those functions put a list in the queue ( queue.put(list) ).
Code for one of the function:

```
def infibeam(isbn,queue):
    #b_price and b_avail are obtained from some where else
    blist =[b_price,b_avail]
    queue.put(blist)
```

The other methods are also similar to this.

I get all the lists in the queue , but how can I know which method has returned which list ?
Please help me. This might be a very silly question, but I am new to python. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [multiprocessing.ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3033952/190597), then you could use `pool.map`:

```
import multiprocessing.pool as mpool

def worker(target, isbn):
    return target(isbn)

def amazon(isbn):
    ...

def bookadda(isbn):
    ...

def infibeam(isbn):
    #b_price and b_avail are obtained from some where else
    return [b_price, b_avail]


pool = mpool.ThreadPool()
isbn = str(9789382711056)
args = [(target, isbn) for target in (amazon,bookadda,infibeam)]
result = pool.map(worker, args)
```

The `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` has the same API as [multiprocessing.Pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), except that the pool is composed of threads instead of processes.

The order of the items in `result` correspond to the order of the items in `args`.

---

In Python3 you could use a [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):

```
import concurrent.futures as CF

with CF.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.map(worker, args)
    result = list(future)
```

There is also [an example using ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) in the documentation showing how to associate the argument with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Have each thread label its return value with a unique tag (a string, the thread function itself, etc). Then have the main thread examine the tags to figure out which function has produced which list.

As a variant of the above, have the thread functions place their return values into a dictionary (again, keyed by a unique tag of some sort).

Comment: This is do-able , but I have around 20 such functions and It would be difficult to search each list to check where the list belongs to. Is there any alternative other than using queue ?

Comment: @GingerNinja23: Encapsulate all this functionality in a class and use it in the 20 places.