# python reuse thread object

Tags: python, multithreading

Is it possible to reuse python thread object to avoid unnecessary creation of the thread?
It could be useful in the following situation. There are many tasks which must be parallelized using thread pool which size is much less than the number of the tasks.

I know that there is multiprocessing.Pool, but it is very important to use threads not processes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python thread pool similar to the multiprocessing Pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Python 3, the best way is definetly to use [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor).

Actually you should read the whole documentation of `concurrent.futures`, it's not long, and there are many great examples.

Comment: Is there something the same for Python 2?

Comment: @itun concurrent.futures has been backported to Py2, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures, or you could try `ThreadPool` mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool, I haven't used it so there's not much more I coud say.