# Why use concurrent.futures instead of multiprocessing pools?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-3.2, concurrent.futures

I'm having trouble understanding why I would use the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#) module. The [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) seems comparable to the [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) for processes, and likewise for the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) vs the [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) module for threads (or even the undocumented [multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3386632/2615940)).

For example, if I want to concurrently map some function call and have an iterator returned, I can use multiprocessing like this:

```
import multiprocessing

bar = [some list]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.imap(foo, bar)
```

Or I can use concurrent.futures with a ProcessPoolExecutor like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

bar = [some list]
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    results = pool.map(foo, bar)
```

It seems like concurrent.futures provides the ability to cancel asynchronous calls before they complete, but the multiprocessing pools provide a lot more methods that can be selected and tailored specifically for your needs, which makes it much more flexible without (as far as I can tell) adding much complexity.

I have read over a couple of resources on the concurrent.futures module:
http://www.developer.com/lang/other/using-the-new-python-32-concurrent-programming-features.html
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/01/16/python-paralellizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-concurrent-futures 
https://gist.github.com/mangecoeur/9540178

But I still don't see what I can gain from it that I didn't already have from process or thread pools. What advantages are there to this new module and when should I use it over the existing pools?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing somewhere that concurrent.futures is a newer implementation (based on futures) with a general approach more compatible with current developments in python.