# How to run multiple for loops in parallel under a single function in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a way to have multithreading implemented for multiple for loops under a single function. I am aware that it can be achieved if we have separate functions, but is it possible to have it under the same function.
For example:

```
def sqImport():
    for i in (0,50):
        do something specific to 0-49
    for i in (50,100):
        do something specific to 50-99
    for i in (100,150):
        do something specific to 100-149
```

If there are 3 separate functions for 3 different for loops then we can do:

```
threadA = Thread(target = loopA)
threadB = Thread(target = loopB)
threadC = Thread(target = loopC)
threadA.run()
threadB.run()
threadC.run()
# Do work indepedent of loopA and loopB 
threadA.join()
threadB.join()
threadC.join()
```

But is there a way to achieve this under a single function?

Comment: Is modifying the function possible?

Comment: Maybe [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) inspires you.

Comment: You should try node.js to achieve this

Comment: Yes i can modify my function @exilit

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I think you really should take a look at `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` if you are going to use it in a productive system. What I describe below is just a possible workaround (which might be simpler and therefore could be used for testing purposes).

You could pass an id to the function and use that to decide which loop you take like so:

```
from threading import Thread

def sqImport(tId):
    if tId == 0:
        for i in range(0,50):
            print i
    elif tId == 1:
        for i in range(50,100):
            print i
    elif tId == 2:
        for i in range(100,150):
            print i

threadA = Thread(target = sqImport, args=[0])
threadB = Thread(target = sqImport, args=[1])
threadC = Thread(target = sqImport, args=[2])
threadA.start()
threadB.start()
threadC.start()
# Do work indepedent of loopA and loopB 
threadA.join()
threadB.join()
threadC.join()
```

Note that I used `start()` instead of `run()` because `run()` does not start a different thread but executes in the current thread context. Moreover I changed your `for i in (x, y)` loops in `for i in range(x,y)` loops, because I think, You want to iterate over a range and not a tuple(that would iterate only over x and y).

---

**An alternative Solution** using `multiprocessing` might look like this:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

# The worker function
def sqImport(data):
    for i in data:
        print i


# The three ranges for the three different threads
ranges = [
    range(0, 50),
    range(50, 100),
    range(100, 150)
    ]

# Create a threadpool with 3 threads
pool = ThreadPool(3)
# Run sqImport() on all ranges
pool.map(sqImport, ranges)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks @exilit. Will try that and check.

Comment: @ exilit, i have different connections in print for different for loops. For ex: print 'port1', 'port2', 'port3' respectively. For for 1st range, it should take print 'port1' and respectively. I doubt that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` which will divide you tasks equally between running threads. 
Follow [Threading pool similar to the multiprocessing Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/python-thread-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool) for more on this.

If you are really looking for parallel execution then go for processes because threads will face python GIL(Global Interpreted Lock).

Comment: How do i use it in my case @Hitul?