# Python multiprocessing when downloading files is slower than normal implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download a number of random articles from an index (Let's say 5000). I tried to generate this program using multiprocessing, however the multi-processed version runs more than twice as slow as the regular version. Why is this?

Code attached:

```
import time
import bs4
import requests
import os
import urllib.parse
import re
import random
from multiprocessing import Process
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp

list_of_files = os.listdir("..\\sample_set")

# Read index file
index = open("C:\\Users\\useradmin\\Desktop\\index.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
lines = index.readlines()

# Seperate random number list into two lists
my_randoms = random.sample(range(1, 18458000), 5000)
input = []
for num in my_randoms:
    input.append(lines[num].split(":")[2].strip("\n"))

start_time = time.clock()

from multiprocessing import Pool

def job(title):
    if not any(title in file for file in list_of_files):
        # Download file using requests.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(job, input)
    print(time.clock() - start_time, "seconds")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could be the multiprocessing overhead. Can you try using a ThreadPool instead ? You can find couple of options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/threading-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool)

Comment: How many files to download? Size of files? Server capacity? Network speep? Depending on that, it is common to use 4 to 10 parallel downloads. And as the bottleneck is normally io, Python threads should be enough (no reason for multiprocessing)