# Using map with queue.put()?

Tags: python

To load a list into a queue in Python, I found this code snippet which failed to work. No items were added to the queue:

```
from queue import Queue
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
q = Queue()

# This code doesn't work
map(q.put, my_list)
q.qsize() # Returns zero, which is unexpected
```

The more verbose solution:

```
for num in my_list:
    q.put(num)
print(q.qsize())  # returns 10 as expected
```

works as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: Using map like this is not idiomatic python. I would stick to the for-loop because you'll need to evaluate the map anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`map(q.put, my_list)` just returns an iterator. Unless you iterate through it, your queue `q` wont be populated

```
>>> q = Queue()
>>> itr = map(q.put, my_list)
>>> q.qsize()
0
>>> _ = list(map(q.put, my_list))
>>> q.qsize()
10
```

Comment: You can demonstrate this by doing `list(map(q.put, my_list))`

Comment: Is using a `for` loop the most pythonic way?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) works:

```
from queue import Queue
l = [i for i in range(10)]
q = Queue()
x = map(q.put, l)
q.qsize()
# Output: 0
for _ in x:
    pass
q.qsize()
# Output: 10
```

You can get what you want using a [`ThreadPool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3386632/6741482):

```
from queue import Queue
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
l = [i for i in range(10)]
p = ThreadPool()
q = Queue()
_ = p.imap_unordered(q.put, l)
q.qsize()
# Output: 10
```

If you want other built-ins:

```
# list comprehension (essentially what map is equivalent to)
_ = [q.put(i) for i in l]

# the `any` method:
_ = any(q.put(i) for i in l)
```

Comment: In other words, in Python 3.x `map()` returns a lazy iterator, rather than a list as in Python 2.x, so you have to explicitly iterate it to get it to do anything.  The "more verbose" version is a better idea anyway, as there's absolutely no point in creating this sequence of `None`s.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why that is not working for you. Maybe your version of python, I am on 2.7.6

```
from queue import Queue
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
q = Queue()

# This code doesn't work
map(q.put, my_list)
q.qsize()

print q.qsize() # 10

while not q.empty():
    print q.get()
```

Comment: I am on Python 3 - could it be a version issue?

Comment: That's definitely the issue. This is a change for Python 3

Comment: I see, it has to do with the fact that `map()` returns an iterator in Python3