# Can openMP be used like multiprocessing?

Tags: cython, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem which is trivially parallelizeable: I need to perform the same operation on 24 cdef objects. I know I could use multiprocess for this, but copying the data/starting a new process takes as long as just doing the computation serially so nothing is gained. Therefore, openMP might be a better alternative.

The operation I'd like to do would look like this with multiprocessing:

```
multiprocess.map(f, list_of_cython_objects)
```

Could something like the below work? Why/why not? I understand I'd have to create an array of pointers to the cython objects, I cannot use lists.

```
from cython.parallel import prange, threadid

with nogil, parallel():

    for i in prange(len(list_of_cython_objects), schedule='guided'):
        f(list_of_cython_objects[i])
```

Comment: If the work itself doesn't invoke the GIL a multithreading approach (no copying to workers) should work fine. But I have never used such an approach in Cython (only pure Python). https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365174/4045774

Comment: Here is some ideas that might work : In your case (multiple execution of the same function), you could use a `multiprocessing.Pool`. Secondly, you want to avoid copying your data, so you could work with `multiprocessing.sharedctypes`, which allow memory mapped object

Comment: @CoMartel that is an interesting idea. Will look into it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that the majority of `f` can be done without the GIL (i.e. it uses `cdef` attributes of the `cdef class`) then this can be made to work pretty well. The only bit that needs the GIL is indexing the list, and you can easily put that in a `with gil` block.

An illustrative example is:

```
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel

cdef class C:
    cdef double x

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

cdef void f(C c) nogil:
    c.x *= 2


def test_function():
    list_of_cython_objects = [ C(x) for x in range(20) ]
    cdef int l = len(list_of_cython_objects)
    cdef int i
    cdef C c
    with nogil, parallel():
        for i in prange(l, schedule='guided'):
            with gil:
                c = list_of_cython_objects[i]
            f(c)
```

So long as the `with gil` blocks are small (in terms of the proportion of computation time) then you should get most of the parallelization speed-up that you expect.

Comment: If you change the c.x *= 2 to c.x *= 2.5 and do it in a loop of 10e7 you get a very nice speedup indeed :) Thanks!