# Tkinter window is waiting for a function that listens for audio input, but I would like window to be active while function runs

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple user interface for a sound recognition program using Tkinter.  The 'record' function waits for sound volume to hit a certain threshold, then records the audio input until the volume drops back below the threshold.  While this record function runs, I have Apple's rainbow beachball cursor and can no longer interact with the window (most importantly, I cannot close it).  I will likely add additional buttons to the window, and would like the user to be able to use the interface while the record function listens.  How would I go about implementing this?  Any help would be appreciated.

```py
import record_tools as rec
from keras.models import load_model 
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
import numpy as np

our_model = load_model('our_model.h5')

class SoundApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #open image for label
        self.img = Image.open('image.jpg')
        self.img = self.img.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        #text for sound predictions
        self.result = StringVar()

        #label for image
        self.l1= Label(parent, image=self.pic).pack()
        #instructions label
        self.l2 = Label(parent, text="Say a word!").pack()
        #label for predictions
        self.l3 = Label(parent, textvariable=self.result).pack()
        root.after(5000, self.predict)

def predict(self):
        #listens for and processes user audio input 
        sw, r = rec.record()
        #normalize audio
        r = rec.norm_for_cnn(r)
        #additional processing
        data, r = rec.process_wav_file(r)
        #make prediction with model
        pred = np.argmax(our_model.predict(np.expand_dims(r, axis=0))[0])

        #update label depending on prediction
        if pred==0: 
            self.result.set('Goat')
        elif pred==1:
            self.result.set('Bird')
        elif pred==2:
            self.result.set('Nemo')
        #call prediction function again
        root.after(3000, self.predict)

root = Tk()
SoundApp = SoundApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE:  A big thank you to martineau for his comment/solution.  It solved my problem.  Also, I ran into one additional problem in trying to make predictions with keras/tensorflow on a separate thread.  After loading my model, it was necessary to add this code:

```py
our_model._make_predict_function()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

And then before calling predict():

```py
with graph.as_default():
     #call prediction function here
```

Further explanation can be found [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/33104180-tensorflow-backend-bug-in-model-_make_predict_function).

Comment: Although I do not have experience with Tkinder personally, I would assume you could just have it record the audio in a separate process, such as with multiprocessing, fork(unix), or subprocess. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html https://www.python-course.eu/forking.php https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you.  I will read up on this and give it a try.

Comment: See [Freezing/Hanging tkinter Gui in waiting for the thread to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696888/freezing-hanging-tkinter-gui-in-waiting-for-the-thread-to-complete)

Comment: I suspect the `rec.record()` is a function waiting for sound input and it is a blocking operation.  If this function supports timeout parameter, use it to minimize the blocking issue.

Comment: @martineau Thank you very much!  Your answer was immensely helpful.  Problem solved.

Comment: Sean: That's good to hear, but the recipe's authors deserve most of the credit for the recipe, of course — but the central idea applies to any tkinter-based application.