# progressbar finishes before set maximum amount

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to display downloaded images in tkinter `Progressbar`, It is working but the progressbar finishes way before the all images are downloaded. I asked a very similar question [tkinter updating progress bar on thread progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591061/tkinter-updating-progress-bar-on-thread-progress), My idea is to update progressbar depending on how many files were created using `len(os.listdir('.'))` to count.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import os,uuid,requests,threading
import numpy as np

def bar():
    temp = 0
    for lst in chunks:
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=download_image, args=(lst)))
    for x in threads:
        x.start()
    while temp<len(links):
        progress['value'] = temp
        root.update_idletasks()
        temp =len(os.listdir('.'))
    print("closing threads")
    for i in threads:
        i.join()
    temp =len(os.listdir('.'))
    progress['value'] = temp
    print('done')
    root.destroy()

with open('image_urls.txt','r') as f:
    links = f.read().split('\n') #links to image urls

threads =[]
chunks = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(links, 10) if i.size>0]
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
root.title('Downloader v1')
progress = Progressbar(root, orient = tkinter.HORIZONTAL, 
              length = 250, mode = 'determinate',maximum=len(links))
progress.pack(pady = 100)
notice = tkinter.Label(root, text=str(len(links)),
                       fg="grey2",)
notice.place(x=350, y=100)
compose_button = tkinter.Button(root, text = 'Start', command = bar)
compose_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are using `maximum=len(links))` but count with `progress['value'] = temp` which may not the same. Furthermore your `def bar(...` uses `while temp<len(links):` and `.join()` which is blocking. Read [While Loop Locks Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639228/python-while-loop-locks-application)

Comment: @stovfl the [https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html](docs) says the `maximum` is the maximum value of progressbar, I am simply feeding it the count, (Ideally) the count should finish (in the `while` loop) before threads are joined.

Comment: ***"maximum is the maximum value of progressbar,"***: That's not the point. May i see the output of `print(maximum)` and `print(temp)` just after `temp =len(os.listdir('.'))`.

Comment: @stovfl the output is "infinite" but it starts at 0 and finishes with `len(links)`, however `len(os.listdir('.'))` shows a different amount than actual (I was refreshing the folder and values don't match)

Comment: ***"and values don't match"***: That's my point, how big is the difference. More ore less then `len(links)`?

Comment: @stovfl it is less than the `len(links)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209603/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-stovfl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: Tkinter `Progressbar` update from multiple `Thread`'s

**Core Point**

```
    .event_generate('<<Progressbar>>')
```

This example uses a virtual event `'<<Progressbar>>'` to increment the `Progressbar['value']`. This **event driven progamming**, needs, no callback, no polling `.after`, no `queue`, to work across `Thread`'s.

---

> **Imports**:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading, time
import random
```

> **The worker `Thread`**

```
class Task(threading.Thread):
    is_alive = 0

    def __init__(self, app, args, name):
        super().__init__(name=name, daemon=True)
        self.args = args[0]
        self.app = app
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        # threaded task
        with self._lock:
            Task.is_alive += 1

        time.sleep(0.01)

        for link in self.args:
            print('Thread[{}]: link:{}'.format(self.name, link))
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))

            with self._lock:
                self.app.event_generate('<<Progressbar>>', when='tail')

        # on end of threaded task
        with self._lock:
            Task.is_alive -= 1
            if Task.is_alive == 0:
                # last Task has finished
                self.app.event_generate('<<COMPLETED>>', when='tail')
```

> **Customized `Progressbar` by inheriting from `ttk.Progressbar`**

```
class Progressbar(ttk.Progressbar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, orient="horizontal", 
                         maximum=0, mode="determinate", length=250)
        parent.bind('<<Progressbar>>', self.value)

    def value(self, event):
        self['value'] += 1
```

> **Usage**:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pb = Progressbar(self)
        self.pb.pack()

        tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start).pack()
        self.bind('<<COMPLETED>>', self.on_completed)

    def start(self):
        links = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        self.pb['maximum'] = len(links)
        chunks = [l for l in zip(links[0::3], links[1::3], links[2::3])]

        for i, args in enumerate(chunks, 1):
            # Task start() at once 
            Task(self, name='Task {}'.format(i), args=(args,))

    def on_completed(self, event):
        # Do cleanups before exiting
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: can you show how close window or do a function once all threads are completed

Comment: @hadesfv See my update, i have added a event `<<COMPLETED>>`. In `def on_completed(...` you can do any cleanups before `self.destroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have accepted the answer above. However, I would post my answer since it is not based on threading, which I think is simpler and may be more suitable. I did not bother adapting my solution to your case since you have accepted the answer:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os



root = Tk()

# I set the length and maximum as shown to demonstrate the process in the 
# proceeding function. Pay attention to the increment r
progress = Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,
            length = 200/5, maximum=200/5, mode = 'determinate')

# Function 


def my_func():
    t=0
    r= 1/5   
    for i in range(200):
        print(i) #whatever function interests you
        t=t+r
        progress['value'] = t
        root.update_idletasks()
  

progress.pack()

# Button
Button(root, text = 'Start', command = bar).pack(pady = 10)


mainloop()
```