# Multiprocessing using mp.Pool to avoid having to wait until all subprocesses are finished?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, operating-system, multiprocessing

I have a Pool of tasks in my code, I want an event to happen once all the tasks in the pool are done. I know about join method but it is stopping my main process of tkinter app, I used a list of Processes and I checked that list using thread whether all the processes are done

Right now I am trying to do like this :

```
my_pool = [mp.Process(task).start() for task in tasks]
# checking if any process alive using a after method of tkinter
if not any(p.is_alive() for p in my_pool):
    # doing some event
```

I wonder if there is a way to do the same using `mp.Pool` instead of `join()`, because it is pausing the main UI of my app until all the process is done in that pool.

Comment: My answer to the question [Freezing/Hanging tkinter Gui in waiting for the thread to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696888/freezing-hanging-tkinter-gui-in-waiting-for-the-thread-to-complete) can probably be adapted to work with a multiprocessing `Pool` instead of multithreading. Be sure to use a `multiprocessing.Queue`.