# Main thread is not in main loop

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, ping

I am trying to ping and get the result of 100+ IPs within 1-2 sec.But running this code using Tkinter is giving me the following error please help me with this.

```
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Attaching the code. Please have a look at it and let me know if any other information is needed

Thank you.

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import socket
import sys
import subprocess
import re
import threading
from tkinter import *
import multiprocessing.dummy
import multiprocessing

class Demo1:
    data=[]
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.label=tkinter.Label(text="Add IP/Hostname")
        self.label.pack()
        self.t=tkinter.Text(self.master,height=20,width=50)
        self.t.pack()
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.master,height=3,width=10, text="OK", command = self.new_window)
        self.button.pack()
        
    def new_window(self):
        self.inputValue=self.t.get("1.0",'end-1c')
        Demo1.data=self.inputValue.split("\n")
        self.master.destroy() # close the current window
        self.master = tkinter.Tk() # create another Tk instance
        self.app = Demo2(self.master) # create Demo2 window
        self.master.configure(bg='#6EBFE4')
        self.master.mainloop()
class Demo2(Demo1):
    t1=[]
    s1=True
    display=[]
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.kas(master)
    def kas(self,master):
        Demo2.t1=Demo1.data
        self.master = master        
        cols = ('IP','Ping status')
        self.listBox = ttk.Treeview(self.master, columns=cols)
        for col in cols:
            self.listBox.heading(col, text=col)
            self.listBox.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
        self.listBox.column('#0',width=50)
        self.listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.ping_range(Demo2.t1)

    def ping_func(self,ip):
        p=[]
        pingCmd = "ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip
        childStdout = os.popen(pingCmd)
        result = (childStdout.readlines())
        childStdout.close()
        p.append(ip)
        if (any('Reply from' in i for i in result)) and (any('Destination host unreachable' not in i for i in result)):
           p.append("sucess")
        else:
           p.append("failed")
        for i,(a) in enumerate(p):
            self.listBox.insert('', 'end',value=(a))           
        return result
    def ping_range(self,ip_list):
        num_threads = 5 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        p = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(num_threads)
        p.map(self.ping_func, [x for x in ip_list])

def main(): 
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried the code using queue and after(). but still getting the same error. not have much idea on these please guide me where i am going wrong and what can i do to correct it. Thank you

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import socket
import sys
import subprocess
import re
import threading
import multiprocessing.dummy
import multiprocessing
import time,  queue
    
    class Demo1:
        data=[]
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            self.label=tkinter.Label(text="Add IP/Hostname")
            self.label.pack()
            self.t=tkinter.Text(self.master,height=20,width=50)
            self.t.pack()
            self.button = tkinter.Button(self.master,height=3,width=10, text="OK", command = self.new_window)
            self.button.pack()
            
        def new_window(self):
            self.inputValue=self.t.get("1.0",'end-1c')
            Demo1.data=self.inputValue.split("\n")
            self.master.destroy() # close the current window
            self.master = tkinter.Tk() # create another Tk instance
            self.app = Demo2(self.master) # create Demo2 window
            self.master.configure(bg='#6EBFE4')
            self.master.mainloop()
    class Demo2(Demo1):
        t1=[]
        s1=True
        display=[]
        
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master=master
            self.kas(master)
        def kas(self,master):
            self.running = True
            self.queue = queue.Queue()  #queue
            Demo2.t1=Demo1.data
            self.master = master        
            cols = ('IP','Ping status')
            self.listBox = ttk.Treeview(self.master, columns=cols)
            for col in cols:
                self.listBox.heading(col, text=col)
                self.listBox.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
            self.listBox.column('#0',width=50)
            self.listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
            #self.ping_range(Demo2.t1)
            self.running = True
            num_threads = 5 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()
            p = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(num_threads)
            p.map(self.ping_func, [x for x in Demo2.t1])
    
        def ping_func(self,ip):
            while self.running:
                pi=[]
                pingCmd = "ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip
                childStdout = os.popen(pingCmd)
                result = (childStdout.readlines())
                childStdout.close()
                pi.append(ip)
                if (any('Reply from' in i for i in result)) and (any('Destination host unreachable' not in i for i in result)):
                   pi.append("sucess")
                else:
                   pi.append("failed")
                self.queue.put(pi)  #Thread value to queue
                m = self.queue.get_nowait()
                print(m)   #getting the correct value but after this statement, getting error as main thread is not in main loop
                for i,(a) in enumerate(m):
                    self.listBox.insert('', 'end',value=(a))
                self.periodic_call()
                
        def periodic_call(self):
            self.master.after(200, self.periodic_call) #checking its contents periodically
            self.ping_func()
            if not self.running:
                import sys
                sys.exit(1)
                    
                     
    
    def main(): 
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        app = Demo1(root)
        root.mainloop()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Tkinter is not thread safe. If all you are doing is pinging then a console application would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaNixon, Thank you for the reply. I am trying to build an application which shows the live pinging status. so i was kinda familiar with python so using tkinter. do you have any idea on how to get the 100+ ips status within 1-2 sec without using this thread concept.

Comment: As @Joshua said, `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading. One way to work around that limitation is to put the results of the threads into a `Queue` and check its contents periodically using `tkinter`'s universal widget [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696888/freezing-hanging-tkinter-gui-in-waiting-for-the-thread-to-complete) to a related question has an example of doing something like that.

Comment: Hi @martineau, Thank you for the reply. I will look into it.

Comment: Hi @martineau, I have looked into your answer and tried to make it correct. As i don't have much idea on it,  still getting the same error. Edited code is pasted above have a look and please guide me where i am going wrong . Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're still getting the `RuntimeError` even with the changes, is because you're is still trying to update the GUI from a thread — the one running the `ping_func()` method — that is *not* the same one running the `tkinter` GUI (which is a required because it doesn't support multithreading).

To fix that I have split `ping_func()` up into two separate parts, one the runs the ping command in another process and appends the results to the queue, and another that updates the GUI — the latter now being done in new method I added named `process_incoming()` (similar to the example to which I referred you).

Also note that the `Demo2` class is no longer a subclass of `Demo1` since there's no reason to do so (and it might confuse matters). I also changed the `self.listBox` attribute to `self.treeview` because that's what it is.

Although those changes alone *would* avoid the `RuntimeError`, in theory the GUI could still "freeze" until all the tasks completed because the `pool.map()` function *blocks* until all the tasks have completed, which could interfere with `tkinter`'s `mainloop()` depending on how long that takes. To avoid that I changed `pool.map()` to `pool.async()` — which doesn't block because it's unnecessary given the `Queue`'s contents are repeatedly polled.

```
import multiprocessing.dummy
import multiprocessing
import os
import socket
import sys
import subprocess
import re
import time
import threading
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import queue


class Demo1:
    data = []
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.label=tkinter.Label(text="Add IP/Hostname")
        self.label.pack()
        self.t=tkinter.Text(self.master,height=20,width=50)
        self.t.pack()
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.master,height=3,width=10, text="OK",
                                     command=self.new_window)
        self.button.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.inputValue = self.t.get("1.0",'end-1c')
        Demo1.data = self.inputValue.split("\n")
        self.master.destroy() # close the current window
        self.master = tkinter.Tk() # create another Tk instance
        self.app = Demo2(self.master) # create Demo2 window
        self.master.configure(bg='#6EBFE4')
        self.master.mainloop()

class Demo2:
    t1 = []
    s1 = True
    display = []

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.kas(master)

    def kas(self,master):
        self.running = True
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        Demo2.t1 = Demo1.data
        self.master = master
        cols = ('IP','Ping status')
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.master, columns=cols)
        for col in cols:
            self.treeview.heading(col, text=col)
            self.treeview.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
        self.treeview.column('#0',width=50)
        self.treeview.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        num_threads = 5 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        p = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(num_threads)
        p.map_async(self.ping_func, [x for x in Demo2.t1 if x])

        self.periodic_call()  # Start polling the queue for results.

    def ping_func(self, ip):
        pi = []
        pingCmd = "ping -n 1 -w 1000 " + ip
        with os.popen(pingCmd) as childStdout:
            result = childStdout.readlines()
        pi.append(ip)
        if(any('Reply from' in i for i in result)
           and any('Destination host unreachable' not in i for i in result)):
            pi.append("success")
        else:
            pi.append("failed")
        self.queue.put(pi)  #Thread value to queue

    def process_incoming(self):
        """ Process any messages currently in the queue. """
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.queue.get_nowait()
                print(msg)
                self.treeview.insert('', 'end', value=(msg))  # Update GUI.
            except queue.Empty:  # Shouldn't happen.
                pass

    def periodic_call(self):
        self.master.after(200, self.periodic_call) # checking its contents periodically
        self.process_incoming()
        if not self.running:
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)


def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @martineau, Thank you so much for the help. I was so confused about this.

Comment: soumya: It's a complex subject, so it's easy to be confused about it. Be sure to note the additional information I just added about the potential pitfalls of using `pool.map()`.

Comment: sure sir, Thanks a lot.. It was of great help to me @martineau