# How to execute two or more functions at a time without delaying GUI elements in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I wrote a code in Tkinter that should execute the function of face recognition as soon as the user click on the button and simultaneously it should redirect to the next frame.

What the problem I am currently facing is, when the user clicks on the button, the face recognition function, that is in my code `gen()`, executes first and as soon as it terminates, it redirects to the next frame.

What I want is both should work at the same time.. Any suggestion please?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import json
  
class tkinterApp(Tk): 
      
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
          
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
          
        container = Frame(self)   
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)  
   
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2): 
   
            frame = F(container, self) 

            self.frames[F] = frame  
   
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
        self.update()
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        if cont not in self.frames:
            self.frames[cont] = cont(self.container, self)
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")

   
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.myStartPage)

    def myStartPage(self,controller):
        super(StartPage).__init__()

        canvas = Canvas(self,width=2300, height=900, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        canvas.pack()

        self.background = PhotoImage(file="Images/background.png")
        canvas.create_image(525,425,image=self.background, tags="B")

        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="Images/bg-top.png")
        canvas.create_image(0,335,image=self.bg, anchor=NW)

        self.my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="Images/start000-befored.png")
        obj1 = canvas.create_image(1200,290,image=self.my_pic1, anchor=NW)

        recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
        cascadePath = "Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)

        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cam.set(3, 640)
        cam.set(4, 480)

        minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
        minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)            

        def get_frame():
            laebl = ""
            names = ['None', 'Marcelo', 'Paula', 'Ilza', 'Z', 'W'] 
            while True:
                ret, img =cam.read()
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                    gray,
                    scaleFactor = 1.2,
                    minNeighbors = 5,
                    minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
                    )
                for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
                    label, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                    if (confidence < 50):
                        label = names[label]
                        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
                    else:
                        label = "unknown"
                        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
                    cv2.putText(img, str(label), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
                    cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)
                    #cv2.imshow('camera',img)
                ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                return label, jpeg.tobytes()

        def gen():
            flag = 1
            while True:
                label, frame = get_frame()
                flag += 1
                if label=="unknown" and flag > 70:
                    cam.release()
                    print("Unknown Face Detected!")
                    break

        canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda event=None : [self.controller.show_frame(Page1), gen()]) 
           
class Page1(Frame): 
      
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
          
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.myPage1)


    def myPage1(self,controller):
        super(Page1).__init__()

        canvas = Canvas(self,width=2300, height=900, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        canvas.pack()

        self.background = PhotoImage(file="Images/background.png")
        canvas.create_image(525,425,image=self.background, tags="B")

        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="Images/bg-top.png")
        bg_tk = canvas.create_image(0,335,image=self.bg, anchor=NW)

        self.bg1 = PhotoImage(file="Images/bg-bottom.png")
        bg1_tk = canvas.create_image(0,335,image=self.bg1, anchor=NW)

        self.after(3000, lambda event=None : self.controller.show_frame(Page2))
        
class Page2(Frame): 
      
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
          
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.myPage2)

    def myPage2(self,controller):
        super(Page1).__init__()
        canvas = Canvas(self,width=2300, height=900, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        canvas.pack()

        self.background = PhotoImage(file="Images/background.png")
        canvas.create_image(525,425,image=self.background)

        self.bg = PhotoImage(file="Images/bg-top.png")
        bg_tk = canvas.create_image(0,70,image=self.bg, anchor=NW)

        self.bg1 = PhotoImage(file="Images/bg-bottom.png")
        bg1_tk = canvas.create_image(0,777,image=self.bg1, anchor=NW)


# Driver Code 
app = tkinterApp()
app.title("My Project")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It won't be easy to do. Suggest you read accepted answer to [Tkinter — executing functions over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342757/tkinter-executing-functions-over-time) which is about even-driven programming in GUIs in general.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think it's relevant in my case. I can't use `after()` method to execute my `gen()` (face recognition function) as I want it in the backend, while on the frontend, it should redirect to the another frame. so basically, both should happens at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading  — and it sounds like that's what you need — in the sense that only one thread in a such an application can access the library. A common workaround is to use a `Queue` to pass information between threads and use `after()` in the GUI thread to periodically check for new data having been put into it (and change the GUI's appearance if appropriate).

Comment: ...see my answer to [Freezing/Hanging tkinter Gui in waiting for the thread to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696888/freezing-hanging-tkinter-gui-in-waiting-for-the-thread-to-complete) for an example.

Comment: Can you help me with the code ? I don't understand properly to to implement this in it :9

Comment: I am not too sure about the intentions but you can try looking into multithreading. Try to create multiple threads for concurrent tasks (if they are independent of each other)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with your code because it isn't a [mre] and is using modules (and hardware I don't have). Unfortunately, that will also prevent others from being able to assist as well…

Comment: @TanishqVyas: Suggest you read earlier preceding comments to avoid posting your own, redundant ones.

Comment: Try running `gen()` in a thread: `canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda e: [threading.Thread(target=gen,daemon=True).start(), self.controller.show_frame(Page1)]) `.  You need to `import threading`.