# tkinter incrementally display infos in scrolledtext from another file

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to display the result of any variable in another file to the scrolltext. My question is: Image I have two python files. py1.py is the main file which contains only scrolledtext widget. And what I need to realize is that I want the result of any variable in py2.py to be consciously (incrementally) displayed in the scrolledtext widget (which is embedded in py1.py).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
py1.py
"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

win = tk.Tk()

text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win)

# for ii in range(100000):
#     mystr = "Step " + str(ii) + "\n"
#     text_area.insert(tk.END, mystr)
exec(open("py2.py").read())

text_area.see(tk.END)
text_area.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

```
"""
py2.py
"""
import tkinter as tk
from py1 import text_area

for ii in range(100000):
    mystr = "Step " + str(ii) + "\n"
    text_area.insert(tk.END, mystr)
```

Comment: ```exec(open("py2.py").read())``` why? Simply ```open(...).read()``` will do

Comment: Hi, Sujay, thanks again for your immediate response.      If i change exec(open("py2.py").read()) to open(...).read(), the py2.py file does not execute. There would be nothing displayed in the scrolledtext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a better approach because it would not require the second script to `import` the first to access its variables (which wouldn't work anyway). Instead have `py1.py` import the second script and call a function in it and pass the variable as an argument. Here's what I mean:

```
"""
py1.py
"""

import py2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

win = tk.Tk()

text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(win)
text_area.pack()

btn = tk.Button(text='Display Results', command=lambda: py2.add_results(text_area))
btn.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Second script:

```
"""
py2.py
"""
import tkinter as tk

def add_results(text_area):
    for ii in range(100000):
        mystr = "Step " + str(ii) + "\n"
        text_area.insert(tk.END, mystr)
        text_area.see(tk.END)
        text_area.update_idletasks()  # Update display.
```

#### Update

To prevent the tight loop in the `add_results()` function from making your application freeze-up until the loop is finished, you need to make use of the universal `after()` widget method to schedule repeated calls to the function until is finished.

So here's a version of the function in the second script showing how to to that:

```
"""
py2.py - version 2.0
"""
import tkinter as tk

def add_results(text_area, ii=0):
    if ii < 100000:  # Not Done?
        mystr = f"Step {ii}\n"
        text_area.insert(tk.END, mystr)
        text_area.see(tk.END)
        text_area.update_idletasks()  # Update display.
        ii += 1
        # Call this func again in 100 ms (0.1 sec).
        text_area.after(100, add_results, text_area, ii)
```

Comment: Thanks very mush, really help for me.    This problem has confused me several days.

Comment: Hello martineau, one annoying thing I found later is that when your code run,  i cannot do anything on the main window, even if  i try to move it, it crashes...

Comment: It's not crashing, it hanging or freezing. That's because the function in your second script is running a *very* tight loop which interferes with tkinter's own `mainloop()` that processes user input. The common way to avoid that by using the universal widget [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method to schedule periodic calls to a function (which again cannot take too long to execute). There are many question about the topic here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i will try after method.  By the way,   is the  thread module   better???

Comment: No, not in this case because tkinter doesn't support threading in the sense that only one thread in a multithreaded application can use it. See the update to my answer showing how to use the `after()` method. There are also ways of using a queues to pass information between threads, which  (also) uses the `after()` method only what it does in this scenario is periodically check the queue for new data and updates the GUI accordingly when some is received.

Comment: One problem is that if I add one additional statement time.sleep(10) to replace a long run time code there, the freeze problem still exists, do you have any idea to avoid that

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to simulate, but trying to change my answer like that is not OK. **Of course** putting a call to a long `sleep` in the `add_results()` function will freeze the program because doing so prevents the `mainloop` from running and processing any GUI-related events including calling the function again in 100 ms.

Comment: In fact,  the phrase    time.sleep(10)     is to imitate a long run code (computation with heavy iteration). Since my main code is long, so i just paste  a small portion here.

Comment: Putting the sleep in `add_results()` does not simulate that, as the function needs to run as quickly as possible. If you have something else in your main code that's taking a long time, then that, too, will make the GUI freeze. You may be able to workaround the issue by executing the slow code in a separate thread, but how to do that with `tkinter` is another topic. See [Freezing/Hanging tkinter GUI in waiting for the thread to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696888/freezing-hanging-tkinter-gui-in-waiting-for-the-thread-to-complete) for an example.