# How to multithread with getattr, one thread per property?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool, getattr

Suppose I have the following object with multiple expensive properties, as so:

```
class Object:

  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num

  @property 
  def expensive_property(self):
    return expensive_calculation

  @property 
  def expensive_property1(self):
    return expensive_calculation

  @property 
  def expensive_property2(self):
    return expensive_calculation
```

Note: The number of expensive properties may increase over time. 
Given a list of `Objects` how could I compute each expensive property per thread, for all objects in the list. I am having a hard time figuring out how I should arrange my pool.

This is kinda what I am trying to achieve:

```
from multithreading.dummy import Pool
from multithreading.dummy import Queue

object_list = [Object(i) for i in range(20)]
properties = [expensive_property2, expensive_propert5, expensive_property9, expensive_property3]


def get(obj, expensive_property):
  return [getattr(expensive_property, o) for o in obj]

tasks = Queue()
for p in properties :
  tasks.put((get, o, p))

results = []

with Pool(len(properties )) as pool:
   while True:
      task = tasks.get()
      if task is None:
        break
      func, *args = task
      result = pool.apply_async(func, args)
      results.append(result)
```

Comment: is computation CPU intensive? https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: @dm03514  not cpu intensive, just lots of sleeps

Answer (score 1):

This is a little crazy because `apply_async` has an [internal queue](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L364) to distribute tasks over the pool.  I can imagine reasons to have another queue around observability or backpressure.  Is your example your full program? or are you enqueuing work from a different process/thread?

If your computation is CPU bound one option could be to remove the queue to make things a little simpler:

```
def wait_all(async_results, timeout_seconds_per_task=1):
   for r in async_results:
      r.get(timeout_seconds)

wait_all(
  [pool.apply_async(get, (o, p)) for p in properties],
  timeout_seconds_per_task=1,
)
```

Like your example above this allows you to distribute computation across your available cpus (pool even defaults to the number of [cpus on your machine](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)).  If your work is IO bound (suggested by your sleep) processes may have diminishing returns.

You'd have to benchmark but for IO bound you could create a thread pool using the same pattern https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034000/594589

Other options could be to use nonblocking IO with event loop such as gevent, or asyncio.  Both would allow you to model the same pool based pattern!

Comment: this is just part of my program. To be honest, I know my example is a bit dumb, especially with the get() method. I actually can multithread it any way I need to, it just needs to get each property on its own thread

Comment: the answer does not need to follow my example, I just wrote that to kinda suggest what i have to do. The problem is much simpler, get each property on its own thread (not process) for all objects in the list