# fast scan port with python

Tags: python, multithreading, scapy

This is my code for port scanner:

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime
import threading

threadlock = threading.Lock()

def TCPort(ip_addr, port):
    time = 1   # max time to send packages to a port is 1 seconds

    threadlock.acquire()
    pkt = IP(dst=ip_addr)/TCP(dport=port,flags="S")
    ans = sr1(pkt, timeout=time, verbose=0)
    if(str(type(ans))=="<type 'NoneType'>"):
        #port is closed
        pass
    elif ans.haslayer(TCP):
         if (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags=="A") or (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags=="SA"):
        # port sent a SYN or SYN-ACK answer, so answer with RST to close
        # the connection and print the port
        sr1(IP(dst=ip_addr)/TCP(dport=port,flags="S"), timeout=time, verbose=0)
        print port,"open".rjust(9-len(str(port)))
    threadlock.release()

#main
ip_addr = "192.168.1.33"

ports = range(1,500)
start = datetime.now()
print "Started on", start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

for port in ports:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t5 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t6 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t7 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t8 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t9 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t10 = threading.Thread(target=TCPort, args=(ip_addr,port))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t5.start()
    t6.start()
    t7.start()
    t8.start()
    t9.start()
    t10.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    t5.join()
    t6.join()
    t7.join()
    t8.join()
    t9.join()
    t10.join()

print "Finished on", datetime.now()-start
```

instead of doing 10 vars for the threads, How can I do the thread in fewer lines and less variables?

*** This question was edited to more specific question

*** IGNORE THIS PARAGRAPH. The system don't let me post the edit because I need to write some more words, so you can ignore this paragraph (by the way, if you read this I'll be glad to learn how an I bypass this limitation)

Comment: Use lists instead or numbered variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a pool-based approach, where you create a set of threads/processes, then feed them the ports you want to check. 
[Threading pool similar to the multiprocessing Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/threading-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool)
is how to do this with threads, which should be all you need in this case. This manages most of the annoying parts of threading for you.

Comment: Well, I need to learn it.... Thanks!