# Single precision rfft

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I seek single precision `rfft` to accelerate computation; `scipy.fftpack.rfft` does this, but returns a real array that packs real and imaginary components in same axis, requiring a post-processing step. I implemented below to obtain the standard complex array, but Numpy's `rfft` ends up being faster for 2D inputs (but slower for 1D). Memory is also of concern, OOM with float64.

Does scipy or another library have a single precision `rfft` implementation that returns the standard complex array? (else, can below be done faster?)

---

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import rfft
from scipy.fftpack import rfft as srfft

def rfft_sp(x):  # assumes len(x) is even
    xf = np.zeros((len(x)//2 + 1, x.shape[1]), dtype='complex64')
    h = srfft(x, axis=0)            
    xf[0] = h[0]
    xf[1:] = h[1::2]
    xf[:1].imag = 0
    xf[-1:].imag = 0
    xf[1:-1].imag = h[2::2]
    return xf

x = np.random.randn(500, 100000).astype('float32')

%timeit rfft_sp(x)
%timeit rfft(x, axis=0)
```

```
>>> 565 ms ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> 517 ms ± 22.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: What kind of performance (increase) are you expecting?

Comment: @anon01 Speed .

Comment: 10%, 100%, 1000%?

Comment: The numbers look quite comparable for `%timeit rfft_sp(x); %timeit rfft(x, axis=0)`

Comment: why do you insist on single precision?

Comment: Changing precision is not the first thing to address if you want better performance.  I'd try 1) performance optimzed package (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365623/improving-fft-performance-in-python/30109600) 2) consider MKL vs OpenBLAS backend, 2) JIT or hw acceleration (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014239/how-to-do-100000-times-2d-fft-in-a-faster-way-using-python), 3) optimization within the package itself.  All of these may get you orders of magnitude better performance than changing the precision

Comment: @anon01 It won't solve memory problems; I could've been clearer on memory requirement, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scipy.fft` works with single precision.

Answer (score 0):

on the machine on which I tested, using scipy.fft.rfft and casting to `complex64` is faster than your implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import rfft
from scipy.fft import rfft as srfft
from scipy.fftpack import rfft as srfft2

def rfft_sp(x):  # assumes len(x) is even
    xf = np.zeros((len(x)//2 + 1, x.shape[1]), dtype='complex64')
    h = srfft2(x, axis=0)            
    xf[0] = h[0]
    xf[1:] = h[1::2]
    xf[:1].imag = 0
    xf[-1:].imag = 0
    xf[1:-1].imag = h[2::2]
    return xf

def rfft_cast(x):  
    h = srfft(x, axis=0)            
    return h.astype('complex64')


x = np.random.randn(500, 100000).astype('float32')

%timeit rfft(x, axis = 0 ) 
%timeit rfft_sp(x ) 
%timeit rfft_cast(x)
```

produces:

```
1.81 s ± 144 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.89 s ± 7.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.24 s ± 9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: The underlying implementation is still float64 which bears memory problems, but I did confirm `scipy.fft` to be faster than `np.fft`.