# Run 5 Threads only at a Time in python

Tags: python

I have a text file which consist of list of dates. I want to pass every date to a shell script as a parameter and run the script for all the specified date from the file.

I want to execute this task in parallel using python. Since the script has complex logic and to monitor the execution I want to run 5 instances at a time. As soon as the scripts are completed python has to start new thread.

```
import threading
import time


class mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.h = i
        # Script will call the function

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Value send ", self.h)


f = open('C:\Senthil\SenStudy\Python\Date.txt').readlines()
num = threading.activeCount()

for i in f:
    print("Active threads are ", num)
    time.sleep(1)
    if threading.activeCount() <= 5:
        thread1 = mythread(i)
        thread1.start()
    else:
        print("Number of Threads are More than 5 .. going to sleep state for 1 mint ...")
        time.sleep(1)
```

I tried using `threading.activeCount()` to get the number of threads running, but from the beginning it says number of threads are 30 (which is number of all date entries in the file).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191051/how-does-thread-pooling-works-and-how-to-implement-it-in-an-async-await-env-lik/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems tailor-made for a python process pool or thread pool. If the input argument to each "thread" is just a date, I think a process pool may be better, as synchronization between threads can be tricky.

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) for the `multiprocessing` module and see if it solves your problem. If you have any questions about it, I'll be happy to clarify.

(An example for a process pool is right at the beginning of the documentation. If you really think you need a thread pool, the syntax would be the same --- just replace `multiprocessing` with [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy).)

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are sure you need threads and not processes, you can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run a fixed number of worker threads to do the job:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


DATE_FILE = 'dates.txt'
WORKERS = 5


def process_date(date):
    print('Start processing', date)

    # Put here your complex logic.

    print('Finish processing', date)


def main():

    with open(DATE_FILE) as date_file:
        dates = [line.rstrip() for line in date_file]

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(WORKERS) as executor:
        executor.map(process_date, dates)
        executor.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you use Python 2, you have to install `futures` library first to make this work:

```
pip install --user futures
```