# How to test python with threading and callback function?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test `async_who` function by pytest.

How do I test callback is called and the return value is 'Bob'

```
import threading


def async_who(callback):
    t = threading.Thread(target=_who, args=(callback,))
    t.start()


def _who(callback):
    return callback('Bob')


def callback(name):
    print(name)
    return name


async_who(callback)
```

Because the `async_who` didn't return value. I can't do this,

```
def test_async_who():
    res = async_who(callback)
    assert res == 'Bob'
```

Comment: Even that it looks very simple your test is too complex. Test every function separately and mock what you don't test. For example `Thread` is well tested already, test that you make the right call, not that the call works (creates a thread).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3386632/3356777) from multiprocessing module or [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) (for python version >= 3.2)
are ways to get the return value of a thread.

#### With concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def async_who(callback):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    res = executor.submit(_who, callback)

    return res.result()

def _who(callback):
    return callback('Bob')


def callback(name):
    print(name)
    return name

def test_async_who():
    res = async_who(callback)
    assert res == 'Bob'
```

#### With multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)


def async_who(callback):
    res = pool.apply_async(_who, args=(callback,))
    return res.get()


def _who(callback):
    return callback('Bob')


def callback(name):
    print(name)
    return name


def test_async_who():
    res = async_who(callback)
    assert res == 'Bob'
```