# Limiting threads to a certain amount and going trough a list

Tags: python, multithreading

I would like to go trough a list that contains maybe 10.000 lines and do so with X amount of threads.
I am wondering how I would tell the threads to take Line1 to LineX and when those threads are finished start a new thread from LineX and so on and so forth.
Right now this code I wrote starts the amount of threads there is in my pagenumbers list.

Any hints or suggestions is appreciated, I am still learning Python!
Thanks in advance.

```js
import re
import random
import threading
import random
import string
import requests
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start = time.time()        
dork = input('Input Search term: ')
pagenumbers = ["0", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50"]

def startscrape(search, page):
    with requests.session() as req:
        headersx = {'Host': 'www.url.com',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
                'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
                }
        url = 'https://www.url.com/' + search + '&first=' + page
        resp = req.get(url, headers=headersx)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
        divfound = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "b_title"})
        urlsfound = re.findall(r'href=\"(.*?)\">', str(divfound), re.S)
        with open('urls.txt', 'a', errors='ignore') as f:
            for urls in urlsfound:
                if 'microsofttranslator' not in urls:
                    f.write(urls + "\n")

threads = [threading.Thread(target=startscrape, args=(dork, page)) for page in pagenumbers]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start))
```

Comment: You could try using a thread pool to have fixed number of threads running and then assign your lines iteratively to the pool. Basically any free thread will take what jobs are left. I think the documentation covers it well enough to convert your current code to work with a thread pool. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033952/threading-pool-similar-to-the-multiprocessing-pool

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: As mentioned, use a thread pool, i.e. [this](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor)