# what is the difference between ThreadPoolExecutor and ThreadPool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool

Is there a difference between `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` and `ThreadPool` from `multiprocessing.dummy`? This [article](https://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line) suggests that `ThreadPool` queries the "threads" (task) to the different "threads" of the CPU. Does `concurrent.futures` do the same or will the "threads" (tasks) query to a single "thread" of a CPU?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `multiprocessing.dummy.ThreadPool` is a copy of the `multiprocessing.Pool` API which uses threads rather than processes, which leads to some weirdness since thread and processes are very different, including returning a `AsyncResult` type which only it understands.

The `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is a subclass `concurrent.futures.Executor` which is a newer simpler API, developped with both processes and threads in mind and so returns a common `concurrent.futures.Future`.

On a very broad and far look, both do the same but `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` does it better.

---

References:

From the [`multiprocessing.dummy` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy):

> `multiprocessing.dummy` replicates the API of multiprocessing but is no more than a wrapper around the `threading` module.
>
> In particular, the `Pool` function provided by `multiprocessing.dummy` returns an instance of `ThreadPool`, which is a subclass of `Pool` that supports all the same method calls but uses a pool of worker threads rather than worker processes.

From the [`multiprocessing.dummy.ThreadPool` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool)

> A `ThreadPool` shares the same interface as `Pool`, which is designed around a pool of processes and predates the introduction of the `concurrent.futures` module. As such, it inherits some operations that don’t make sense for a pool backed by threads, and it has its own type for representing the status of asynchronous jobs, `AsyncResult`, that is not understood by any other libraries.
>
> Users should generally prefer to use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, which has a simpler interface that was designed around threads from the start, and which returns `concurrent.futures.Future` instances that are compatible with many other libraries, including `asyncio`.